# Does TypeScript support mutually exclusive types?

Tags: typescript

I have a method that takes a parameter. I would like TypeScript to verify that the object being passed in (at compile-time, I understand run-time is a different animal) only satisfies one of the allowed interfaces.

Example:

```
interface Person {ethnicity: string;}
interface Pet {breed: string;}
function getOrigin(value: Person ^ Pet){...}

getOrigin({}); //Error
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc'}); //OK
getOrigin({breed: 'def'}); //OK
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc', breed: 'def'});//Error
```

I realize that `Person ^ Pet` is not valid TypeScript, but it's the first thing I thought to try and seemed reasonable.

Comment: I *think* what you're looking for is [Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html).  AFAIK TypeScript doesn't support exclusive types.

Comment: For people looking to keep only one property among all the keys of an interface, I suggest using [oneOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591230/typescript-convert-a-tagged-union-into-an-union-type)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094#issuecomment-373782604), you could use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) to write a XOR type:

```
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
```

And now your example works:

```
interface Person {ethnicity: string;}
interface Pet {breed: string;}
function getOrigin(value: XOR<Person, Pet>) { /* ... */}

getOrigin({}); //Error
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc'}); //OK
getOrigin({breed: 'def'}); //OK
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc', breed: 'def'});//Error
```

Comment: That XOR is so handy! How could this be extendd to support multiple mutualy exclusive types? Could you extend your answer to support `XOR<Person, Pet, Car, Tree, ..., House>` ?

Comment: One would need to build up an according chain (I suspect it works because of transitivity?!):
`type XOR3<S, T, U> = XOR<S, XOR<T, U>>;`

Comment: @maninak A little late to the party, but [this](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y9wcpxuk) (TS playground) would accomplish what you were looking for with `OneOf<[Person, Pet, Car, Tree, ..., House]>`

Comment: Horrifying @tjjfvi... :)

Comment: @tjjfvi Did you write that? I'd like to be able to credit the creator when I use it :)

Comment: @ConnorDooley Yes, I did. It was a while ago, so here's a cleaner version: https://tsplay.dev/wgLpBN

Answer (score 19):

You can use the tiny npm package [`ts-xor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xor) that was made to tackle this problem specifically.

With it you can do the following:

```js
import { XOR } from 'ts-xor'
 
interface A {
  a: string
}
 
interface B {
  b: string
}
 
let A_XOR_B: XOR<A, B>
 
A_XOR_B = { a: 'a' }          // OK
A_XOR_B = { b: 'b' }          // OK
A_XOR_B = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }  // fails
A_XOR_B = {}                  // fails
```

You can even XOR more than one types like so:

```js
XOR<A, B, C, D, E, F> // supports XORing up to 200 type arguments
```

> Full disclosure: I'm the author of ts-xor. I found that I needed to implement the XOR type from repo to repo all the time. So I published it for the community and me and in this way, I could also add tests and document it properly with a readme and jsdoc annotations. The implementation is what @Guilherme Agostinelli shared from the community.

Answer (score 4):

To augment Nitzan's answer, if you *really* want to enforce that `ethnicity` and `breed` are specified mutually exclusively, you can use a mapped type to enforce absence of certain fields:

```
type Not<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: void;
};
interface Person {ethnicity: string;}
interface Pet {breed: string;}
function getOrigin(value: Person & Not<Pet>): void;
function getOrigin(value: Pet & Not<Person>): void;
function getOrigin(value: Person | Pet) { }

getOrigin({}); //Error
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc'}); //OK
getOrigin({breed: 'def'}); //OK

var both = {ethnicity: 'abc', breed: 'def'};
getOrigin(both);//Error
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions):

```
interface Person {
  readonly discriminator: "Person"
  ethnicity: string
}

interface Pet {
  readonly discriminator: "Pet"
  breed: string
}

function getOrigin(value: Person | Pet) { }

getOrigin({ }) // Error
getOrigin({ discriminator: "Person", ethnicity: "abc" }) // OK
getOrigin({ discriminator: "Pet", breed: "def"}) // OK
getOrigin({ discriminator: "Person", ethnicity: "abc", breed: "def"}) // Error
```

Answer (score 3):

For a bigger list of options you can use [StrictUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678379):

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type WhatYouWanted = StrictUnion<Person | Pet | Car>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of TS v4.7, I found [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to be the simplest solution:

```
interface Circle {
    radius: number;
}

interface Polygon {
    sides: number;
}

type Either<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> | Omit<B, keyof A>;

const mutuallyExclusiveProps: Either<Circle, Polygon> = { radius: 5 };

mutuallyExclusiveProps.sides = 5; // Error
```

Comment: Works fine only until you don't have a common property in both of them, say `perimeter`. Then, you won't be able to pass neither a valid Circle nor a valid Polygon into the thing ;)

Comment: Correct. I thought that was the whole reason for this type to exist. I personally use this trick in my front-end projects to define strictly mutually exclusive props for a particular component which I can then go and spread.

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely be one of the use cases, but I stumbled into this post while looking for a way to structure a tree graph, say, with leaf nodes that have value, or branch nodes that have children, but also leaves and branches could have properties in common, inherited from BaseNode. So in a resulting structure I wanted XOR<Branch, Leaf>, so to guarantee there can't be children and value at the same time. I solved it through an explicit `never` prop BTW, so `children?: never` in a Leaf and `value?: never` in a Branch and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution. We have an unexported base type that we use as a blueprint for the exported type, in which only one property is allowed, and the others are `never`.

```js
type OnlyOne<Base, Property extends keyof Base> = Pick<Base, Property>
& Partial<Record<keyof Omit<Base, Property>, never>>;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxPCAeAQgQwM4QDRQAKATgPaTGhQQAewEcAJtlANYQikBmUWuAfFAC8RAJYBjVhhz4iZCqH4AoAGRFMlUZgSoAShHGlijVO048YAW1HBpuAiXIRKIfgTgQAbs-78A3EpKAPRBUAAqABaiLNgRpACuCIxQcKTAUABG0LRgRvSMSqCQvDIAYqSkwlAA3kpQ9ZkaAFwp8ZZZxAENjQBeLdjAxKJwAOZdDQCO8TQtcG0dANoAukoAvlCBRdDllSJKAD6wiMgedhA7BADkGRqXyofwSChnF1DXmD13B0dPp3znFSuUxoXyUhjgA0axBaOyq1Ru0KgABYAEyrMGkCGkBAQAB0CFIIwAFAApADKMAAcriBkNRqIuCAiQiAJQswLgyE3PpQWEieEfFrvT7oznYvEE4nkqk0wbDEYMpnctkczGQ4EwipwjVQBYARjwKLwAGYlqK1eL8YTSRTqbT5YqicCVcFQpS0lAAO5GVjy11QTnpYaebSiRia3Y1BEtVEEblC7mXAg6-WGk1m-1inFWqW22V0hWMonB0OMNlAA)

Answer (score -3):

You can use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
function getOrigin(value: Person | Pet) { }
```

But the last statement won't be an error:

```
getOrigin({ethnicity: 'abc', breed: 'def'}); // fine!
```

If you want that to be an error then you'll need to use [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function getOrigin(value: Pet);
function getOrigin(value: Person);
function getOrigin(value: Person | Pet) {}
```

Comment: Union types doesn't solve the problem and is kinda what the OP is asking what to replace it with, but function overload works very nicely for this use case.