# Reuse component loaded from a Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to write a React + Redux component (with typescript) that will be loaded from a route:

```
<Route exact path="/a-path-to-my-page" component={MyComponent} />
```

However I would like to load the same component inside a Dialog component, my problem is that I need to define a type extending RouteComponentProps to have access to history, location, and other props when loading from the route but I don't need all of these props when loading the component from the Dialog, is there any way to define some kind of conditional type such as:

```
type MyComponentPropsRouter = RouteComponentProps.RouteComponentProps &
  MyComponentPropsFromStateType &
  MyComponentPropsFromDispatchType;

type MyComponentPropsNoRouter = MyComponentPropsFromStateType & MyComponentPropsFromDispatchType;

type MyComponentAllProps = MyComponentPropsRouter "or" MyComponentPropsNoRouter  //Is this possible?
```

Thanks in advance!

I've tried with an XOR as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) but it is not what I'm looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating my own interface with the desired attributes from RouteComponentProps and leaving the other ones as conditional the following way:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
   history: History<any>;
   location?: Location<any>
   match?: match<{}> 
}

type MyComponentAllProps = MyComponentProps & MyComponentPropsFromState & MyComponentPropsFromDispatch;
```

Is that the only way?

Thanks again!