# Several questions about TypeScript mutex types

Tags: typescript

I want the `option` to have a `path` attribute or a `children` attribute, but not both. And can be correctly derived during use。

First, I do this:

```
type Option = {name: string, path: string} | {name: string, children: Option[]}
declare const option: Option
option.path // Property 'path' does not exist on type 'Test'
```

[Online test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvFBDAthAFxQDOwATgigOYA0UYuwAFieVbQL5QA+2eQu0rV6UAMYsEAGwAmFCChJxEqANoBdLgChZEcdNwKJqclCTxkS2JdTaLqlADomrKAHp3UAOosQAfgBCIA)

Then, I use this way:
[Does Typescript support mutually exclusive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types)

```
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;


type Option = {name: string} & XOR<{path: string}, {children: Option[]}>

// const option: Option = {name: '1', path: ''} // ok
// const option: Option = {name: '1', children: []} // ok
// const option: Option = {name: '1', value: '', children: []} // error, but ok

declare const option: Option

if (option.children) option.children.concat()
else option.path.toLocaleUpperCase()

if (option.path) option.path.toLocaleUpperCase()
else option.children.concat() // why ?!
```

[Online test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7ADwBUA0UCqAfFALxQDeUA2gApRwB2UAogB4DGANqgCYQYBrCCGQAzKLihCR4ogF0A-AC4oDCADcIAJygBfANwAoUJCgANAPIAlbHiKkoACixQAPgQCUUCK2AQGPADOUMgARgBWEOzAUApO8EhomJL2AGSebvEIKOgY+HhYxOlYXiou7vhGhsbg0BZgwHDITGTkDACGALYQKoHAWowA5rpQ6ZY25GDtSL39Q7p45OyIcJw8Wv4q9Y3NVHK6hNUA9EdQ7M19IQ1NDFvXzQ5tXT1QAOQAjK94UzNvryMnEICQyA84MS7Ie63KDbG6PDrdFQfL5nFZrDbQvYA07IYGgi4xSE7aGwh6tBEvZF4dTtbiUlHLVbrTbUfZQQHaLTILR4ULoIHVPhcdobM4Eq7Eu7E6pwcSOIk3AB0jPR-i8CuayrRzIYyua7Gmjg8hggnEC0A1up+iEVwGQABlkAbOBB8GBIFoAMLtc1GmVyy2K63qqFB6Y2u2O52u93ab2+42m80SpUqnV6hgG4BG9mnADuiBAsQAhIYgA)

So, I want to know what is the reason for the above two errors? And how to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

```
type Option = {name: string, path?: never, children: Option[]} | {name: string, path: string, children?: never};


declare const option: Option

if (option.children) option.children.concat()
else option.path.toLocaleUpperCase()

if (option.path) option.path.toLocaleUpperCase()
else option.children.concat() //fixed
```

Hope this helps

EDIT You want discriminated union types, is essentially the true name for it.
You can find the equivalent typescript documentation here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: Thanks! But [Your method is wrong](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvFBDAthAFxQDOwATgigOYA0UYuwAFiShAG4QUMDGLBABsAJhQgoScRKgDaAXQC+UAD7Y8hEuSq0GTVlsrV6UAcLET2XHooDcAKEciIfIbnGnU5KEnjJJsH6ojr4yKAB0+izhwEgAyka0ABQAlFAA9OlQLL7QuGg8FEgU9qH+4Wai4hF8qHzMqRlZOZBQ+VCFxUA)

Comment: `type Option = {name: string, path?: never, children: Option[]} | {name: string, path: string, children?: never};`

Comment: [not fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvFBDAthAFxQDOwATgigOYA0UYuwAFgPwkoQBuEFDAYxYIANgBMKEFCTiJUAbQC6AXygAfbHkIlyVWgyasdlavShDREqRyhdeFZQG4AUK7EQBI3JPOpyUJHhkaVgg1FcEADMoAApAuRQAOgtxSRQASgCwpJSrHNQBZhj05wgRUmh44MTDFkTgJAAZJEKRCABVMEgKAGFcCuKI6LjsmuYWTKrUMdZ6ppbcNs7uvoGSsoqshOThVKlkgqLMgHpj2yRgKEiEAA8gA)