# Typescript - how to combine Union and Intersection types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, union-types

I have the following component:

```
export enum Tags {
  button = 'button',
  a = 'a',
  input = 'input',
}

type ButtonProps = {
  tag: Tags.button;
} & ({ a?: string; b?: undefined } | { a?: undefined; b?: string }) &
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'];

type AnchorProps = {
  tag: Tags.a;
} & ({ a?: string; b?: undefined } | { a?: undefined; b?: string }) &
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'];

type InputProps = {
  tag: Tags.input;
} & ({ a?: string; b?: undefined } | { a?: undefined; b?: string }) &
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['input'];

type Props = ButtonProps | AnchorProps | InputProps;

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, tag }) => {
  if (tag === Tags.button) {
    return <button>{children}</button>;
  }
  if (tag === Tags.a) {
    return <a href="#">{children}</a>;
  }
  if (tag === Tags.input) {
    return <input type="button" />;
  }
  return null;
};

// In this instance the `href` should create a TS error but doesn't...
<Button tag={Tags.button} href="#">Click me</Button>

// ... however this does
<Button tag={Tags.button} href="#" a="foo">Click me</Button>
```

This has been stripped back a little to be able to ask this question. The point is I am attempting a Discriminated Union along with intersection types. I am trying to achieve the desired props based on the tag value. So if `Tags.button` is used then JSX's button attributes are used (and `href` in the example above should create an error as it is not allowed on `button` element) - however the other complexity is I would like either `a` or `b` to be used, but they cannot be used together - hence the intersection types.

What am I doing wrong here, and why does the type only work as expected when adding the `a` or `b` property?

### Update

I've added a playground with examples to show when it should error and when it should compile.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHFgHYCupAKsgHN0Abzpw4AIy4wYEDnAC85KTLlkANGJSLyyDVuAcw0nWUPGY+gL4MYATzBY4AYRITDyGMDkAFYmHQlAAotAB84YRQAfgAuOFQYKEMBGklYuA4sADcsKDgbcXDI5HTMnKhUiXSEpI4BfLoASno6e0c4ACFpWQ4-CACdUXEYQTj+IQA6FR76KzgAMhc3Dy9ff3RFrQApAGUADQmASQ5Ew1RgXABRABssEE4YVABtMmm1AF0WtqcAQQ5cAAW0D6AyUQzgIwEY0EqAmyFmCyWIHcHE83l66wW232RxOtXOV1u9xOzzIek+tgcTmOFhBgQiWkh0Mm5mkCMWrmRK3RdKx4l2B2Opw4BJudwepNZlgprSpcF5Si6qgx-XQ4T+gOBmPCNOkdJauDkCU63TkcWweBgEwAYs4ADx0gB8OiCkUBwGuABNKBx1BDBPlGopneDgAQ4EFIYoFEpxrC3hwg+DxJQYFwoPI7QnHcJ3V6fVY7QB6bP0cQFOBhiNRmOxmFwpNaFNYNMZuB25BwAGUAgKABEAGI+zm897OIWi8hHWWGuIq5GA7W4HGJlLG+Jm63M1KIVT+wm+3Ai9OtBXU+n5NxrtdZi06EWi8uAVhUE5UECuF72FBiHlPVwnFkLsewyCB4AkLBkhQa8IAAdywT04DkbQE3YIkHjgABaLs4OyXJlDIOBPQgF9QPgXJfywuBYIBOwojoQ0RXgTslDtJUen9AQFGEFcEzmbssF7QdD2QfsCAgCBh2ca4LgAazge5i3YuRHQYo1wJ0NjTXkSFuN47T+J7fsh0daS5IUrAlO01T70fXhn1feIPy-WDoFktSmLgXBNOUnTBD0+s+JQMSJKkmTcHkxSi181TGONRDWN8ziAsmIKJBCyTTPCyLLOi6yPONJxEu05KeMCgysvMqKYoYB8n2AdB3wgT9EIo6AUHQAADZBOpQDhEM6iRetwZAODIcCnC4V9ENkAQW2fKACsIHySt0srUoM4LhMkBQyTISqIosqzlUdIA)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example there are 2 problems that have to be solved and both stem from the same "issue" (feature).

In Typescript, the following doesn't work as we would sometimes want:

```js
interface A {
  a?: string;
}

interface B {
  b?: string;
}

const x: A|B = {a: 'a', b: 'b'}; //works
```

What you want is to explicitly exclude B from A, and A from B - so that they can't appear together.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) discusses the "XOR"ing of types, and suggests using the package [ts-xor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xor), or writing your own. Here's the example from an answer there (same code is used in ts-xor):

```js
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
```

Now, with this we can finally solve your problem:

```js
interface A {
  a?: string;
}

interface B {
  b?: string;
}

interface C {
  c?: string;
}

type CombinationProps = XOR<XOR<A, B>, C>;

let c: CombinationProps;
c = {}
c = {a: 'a'}
c = {b: 'b'}
c = {c: 'c'}
c = {a: 'a', b: 'b'} // error
c = {b: 'b', c: 'c'} // error
c = {a: 'a', c: 'c'} // error
c = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'} // error
```

---

More specifically, your types will be:

```js
interface A {a?: string;}
interface B {b?: string;}

type CombinationProps = XOR<A, B>;

type ButtonProps = {tag: Tags.button} & JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'];
type AnchorProps = {tag: Tags.a} & JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'];
type InputProps = {tag: Tags.input} & JSX.IntrinsicElements['input'];

type Props = CombinationProps & XOR<XOR<ButtonProps,AnchorProps>, InputProps>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a and b not optional, but instead use a union type (|) which corresponds to inclusive OR. It is intersected with the non-conditional properties (never). So now ts can correctly differentiate between them:
Update

```
type ButtonProps = {
  tag: Tags.button;
  a?: string;
  b?: string
} & 
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'];
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUFgB6SxxYB2ArqQCrIA5ugDejOHABG3GDAic4AXnLTZ8sgBpxKJeWSbtwTmBm6yRkzAMMAvo0YwAnmCxwAQjLmcACsTDplMQYJGCEALjgBYQA6VS96YJQAfgjUGCgjQQSJSRS4NIzOQUYbOAAyOG0AKQBlAA1ogElOdKNUYFwAUQAbLBAuGFQAbTI49QBdBIdnVwBBTlwAC2hfCH9dIJDwyKFUaOQE0oqACm0JAB84ERRU1qKaKTzOLAA3LCg4O0SLq+SI57eUAekluhUEn20AEpytV6k0WoV2l1ev0WsMyPpJvYGE4XHBmpZVutAtpQoIIlE9hYZIdynBTt84JdrshQZlgU9Xu8IYzmX84AD3sC2UUeRJoWVYQ1mnckT0+gN0dSrFiGNM8USAu5PPJNUy4PMlis-OhLgSZJqpgxcPI0tq1JwItg8DBogAxADCAB5NQA+XTHa5LYDdAAmlE4GjgZM+0MU-s2cGABHpMcU6Z2MTGnGhiYklBg3CgCi92d9ImDYYjNi9AHoy9kxUmU8c0xnKftc2c4AWiyXkHBFpQCIoAEQAYlH5cr4a4NdryF9ja+EmTqaESnbu2iyq7jN7xbgXuV0ZmY+zo7gtaX2hXPawhcPPG63UOVsYtdrkUWwHQMCHEAAO7oMgCjvMQcChtwrhyIOw6MDanB2vAyheh4DrRkIigiB22alEOWAjhOl7IGOBAQBAU4et0HQANZwP0dboV4vofl+fCLFgqCuIB0C0QhtrwOCqHMfImGCNhuE6pwpSkaO5GUb61F0QxWBMdJrHWoJcDdLoaHSeJknbnhUhkRRVE0bg9GMbWomcJpiF2rgel2YZOHGdJsljpOpkYmQSmWdZam2RpQA).

Comment: That's the thing - I don't want `a` or `b` to be required - I need them both to be optional. I've added this to your example, and I think it works. I've added example to my original question.

Comment: I thought I had it working, but turns out I can't make them both optional :(

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Sorry, now `a` and `b` can be used together - I've updated your playground to show examples at the bottom http://shorturl.at/jMPW8

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use the following technique to create generic functional components but it works for your case as well. The trick is to declare the component as `function` rather than `const` to be able to make it generic. That allows for props to be generic which in turn allows you to do:

```
export enum Tags {
    button = 'button',
    a = 'a',
    input = 'input',
  }

  type Props<T extends Tags = Tags> = JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] & {
    tag: T;
  } & ({ a?: string; b?: never } | { a?: never; b?: string });

  function Button<T extends Tags>({ children, tag }: Props<T>) {
    if (tag === Tags.button) {
      return <button>{children}</button>;
    }
    if (tag === Tags.a) {
      return <a href="#">{children}</a>;
    }
    if (tag === Tags.input) {
      return <input type="button" />;
    }
    return null;
  }

  // These should error due to href not being allowed on a button element
  const a = <Button tag={Tags.button} href="#" a="foo">Click me</Button>
  const b = <Button tag={Tags.button} href="#">Click me</Button>

  // These should work
  const c = <Button tag={Tags.button} a="foo">Click me</Button>
  const d = <Button tag={Tags.button} b="foo">Click me</Button>
  const e = <Button tag={Tags.button}>Click me</Button>

  // This should error as `a` and `b` can't be used together
  const f = <Button tag={Tags.button} a="#" b='a'>Click me</Button>
```

The only drawback is that you can't directly type the `Button` component, you can't say `function Button<T>` is a `React.FC<Props<T>>`, you can only type its props and return type.

Check the [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHFgHYCupAKsgHN0Abzpw4AIy4wYEDnAC85KTLlkANGJSLyyDVuAcw0nWUPGY+gL4MYATzBY4ABWJhUAHl7smMTgBN0fiEdYNQAPh0AKQBlAA0AOgBJDhgoQ1RgXABRABssEE4YVABtXgBdOAAyOFFxGEEALjheeitquAAKYRQAfmbUNMMBGkl+uA4sADcsKDh2gB9avubJmahRiXHB9I4BeYBKejoCLg58YDk4ACFpWQ4vHz8OQJbBCO64XAALYFz-SgcdRwBr7KzNVwQdxecIHWoGAhdUGKBRKMIJFT3OF1cRwSgwLhQeQeTFycLCH5-AGcKweAD0pI44Xo4hs4mAiM6yNRaPeCWQ2K04nxhOJyDg30oBAUACIAMQy8mU-6A2l05DMrRsuAcpGCFG8oQJczSQW4vFYAlEuAeE3weyOWWMmVwOma1laEXW7i5XJtBh0uktb5YVBOVDfCBcf7sKDEOb+LhOWQSqUTCDwCRYYYoX0QADuWH8cCu4sZ7HyhVSdFwckG2iUHluqnkoIUwnRjPakqw0vlLuQsoIEAgioAwrksgBrOCFenN+7hGt1zM6Jt3K5tjt8rup3uyhXhCfT2dYecbpkBoO8ENhuARqMx-PQKfLjj13BrhebwTtzsX9pBxlYdRyPSdcBnOc6W-S9a3feBi0bGCQV-bcjV3CQhxHcdwMgs9oIvJc4PrJwkIvFCBD-HcALAk8oJgpc6EDYNgHQB9o2LWZ4xQdAAANkF4lAXjgXiJEE3BkA4MhMycLgw2LWQBEtEMoDfetETIlsKKo9CAJQA8XUwsg9FoiDT3PFtwiAA) (I left your examples at the bottom)

**EDIT** I updated the code with examples from your question and fixed the playground link

Comment: Sorry, your playground link isn't displaying your example.

Comment: @leepowell I fixed the playground but just in case also pasted the whole code with your examples in the answer

Comment: Thanks - would you mind explaining what the `T extends Tags = Tags` does? I understand the extending part, but am unsure of the `=` - I just modified your example to remove that and it still worked.

Comment: Oh yes sorry not necessary - sometimes i want to only partially specify the type arguments and let TypeScript do the rest. If for example i have a type that takes two arguments and i only want to specify the first one I use = [something] to specify the default. Just like optional function parameters actually

Comment: Also a small note - I mentioned you can't directly type the `Button` function as `React.FC`. Just wanted to say there is a workaround should that be necessary but well I usually prefer not to use it. You can't type it directly BUT you can type a return value of an (unused) function like so: `const someUnusedFunction = <T>(): React.FC<Props<T>> => Button;`.