# Defining at least 1 property of a set in typescript

Tags: typescript

I see that you can do mutually exclusive properties like this in TS

```
type A =
  | { a: "common"; m: any; n: undefined }
  | { a: "common"; m: undefined; n: any };
```

But how do I create a type that has at least 1, but not neither. And without being verbose...

```
type A = {a: "common"} & ({m: any} | {n: any});
```

Does that do it? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic type to require at least one property like this:

```
type AtLeastOne<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    [K in U]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>
}[U]
```

and then define your `A` type like this

```
type A = { a: "common" } & AtLeastOne<{
  m: any;
  n: any;
}>;
```

but that might be too verbose for you :)

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAgiAMlAhgZxAeQHZQDwAqANDAKoxQAeIU2AJmjANZRgD2AZjATALzOtO3AHx8YAb2AxpMANoBpGAEtsZALoBaAPwAuGACUoARwCuSgE5Q6eAApKAxk0Il5w0QDIYNlOZBKUADZ4mAC2SiDOMK7CwAC+sqRqwKCQsHBi4jAoegBE9mwhIWzYOTCxMJ4IyOhYuHiS0iF6GOYqAOYA3FIw2M0grdidccJdwPnYGDCUeun8DVm5+YXFOUTdTTA5AF6rcaPjk5TT8Bnd2ZtLRSVrjbk7Nz25YLux+8WHRzOn0ud5BVe7aS9TbPNavZIHEBTI7HWYSM6Lf4rMFdIA)

Comment: What does `type A = {a: "common"} & ({m: any} | {n: any});` do?

Comment: @Thomas exactly the same as my `type A` (exactly what you intend to)

Answer (score 1):

```
type Combine<A, B> = A | B | A & B
type A = { a: "common" } & Combine<{ m: any }, { n: any }>
```

Comment: is this different than `type A = {a: "common"} & ({m: any} | {n: any});`

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't do it, because for instance `{ a: "common", m: 1, n: 2 }` is assignable to your second A, but not the first, so they're not the same type.

The accepted answer of [Does Typescript support mutually exclusive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) defines an XOR type, I think if you do like, maybe replacing the 'never' in the Without type with 'undefined'

```
type A = { a: "common" } & XOR<{ m: any }, { n: any }>
```

You have what you want

edit - oh I misread your question.