# Type with one unique property of two doesn't work correct

Tags: typescript

I want to set type, where could be one of two types with own unique properties, but typescript allows me to write two properties when I create variable.

example:

```
type some = {
  lol?: string;
  number?: number;
}

type A = {foo: string} & some | {bar: number} & some;
```

I see in description I can set object with "foo" or object with "bar", but typescript allows me to write object with two properties:

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is the precedence of the `|` and `&` operators when defining types. What happens if you break it up into smaller `type` declarations first?

Comment: TS behaves exactly as he asked it to, it is not exclusive or, it is fine for that type to be both of those

Comment: Do you mean `type A = ( { foo: string } & some ) | ( { bar: number } & some );` - or do you mean `type A = { foo: string } & ( some | ( { bar: number } & some );` - or something else?

Comment: TypeScript isn't complaining because the type of `m` is larger than the type of `A` which is allowed, by-design. If you want stricter types (i.e. insisting that an object **does not** have a particular property) then consider using TypeScript's utility types.

Comment: It is a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types i think

Comment: Just to be clear `type FooBar = { foo: string } | { bar: number }; const a: FooBar = { foo: '', bar: 1 };` typechecks. Because unions are not exclusive. If you want to have exclusive property checks you can have descriminated union `type FooBar = { foo: string; kind:  'foo' } | { bar: number, kind: 'bar' }; const a: FooBar = { kind: 'foo', foo: '', bar: 1 };` will raise type error

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE5QLxQN5QGYIBcUAzsKgJYB2A5lAL5QA+OUARmsVQK4C2bEdPQDcAKFEBjOFTJRkxeEjSZWBOMQDkGgDTtOUAIwMxo0JCgARCiQmVe1ZMAgATRSnRZcAa2rPNanXwiUnJqOkYWb19NDlRA2K4+ASETAHpUqAABYBIAWggAD0gJYHzUVDhUSWlZNmIrGzsHJ1cEdxUoqj8oDQDdNU14-SMRIA

Comment: @Dai I tried your variants, but they work the same as my. 
i don't understand why m is larger? I can't put other properties what I am not write in type and I have the type with one of 2 small types, so why I can write key from each other if they have different keys.

Comment: @YuriiHorchynskyi JavaScript+TypeScript types work very differently to nomitive types (i.e. structs and classes) in languages like Java, C# and C++. Remember that every `object` in JavaScript/TypeScript is actually more like a `Dictionary<String,Object>` than a true class.