# TypeScript: is there a way to define a function, which must and only take one out of two as its argument

Tags: typescript

for example, I have a function called `foo`.

Either `foo({a: bar})`  or `foo({b: baz})` is valid but it cannot be `foo({})` or `foo({a: bar, b: baz})`

How do I define the types for this function to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Typescript support mutually exclusive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)