# Building mapped exclusive type in typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have the following type (simplified):

```
type ValueRepresents = {
    boolean: true
    number?: false
    other?: false
} |
{
    boolean?: false
    number: true
    other?: false
} |
{
    boolean?: false
    number?: false
    other: true
}
```

My actual type has many more possible keys.  Is there a way to generate this type from a list of possible keys to make it only valid to have one key with value set to true?   Something like:

```
type ValueTypes = "boolean" | "number" | "other"
type ValueRepresents <T extends ValueTypes> = {
    [k in ValueTypes]: k extends T ? true : false
}
const a: ValueRepresents<"boolean"> = {
    boolean: true,
    number: false,
    other: false,
}
```

But I'm aiming for being able to use:

```
// should pass
const a: ValueRepresents = { boolean: true }

// should pass
const a2: ValueRepresents = {
    boolean: true,
    number: false,
}

// should error
const a3: ValueRepresents = {
    boolean: true,
    number: true,
}

// should error
const a4: ValueRepresents = {}
```

I also tried [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229567/539490) but was not yet successful with:

```
type ValueRepresents <T extends ValueTypes> = {
    [k in Exclude<T, ValueTypes>]?: false
} & { [k in T]: true }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try creating an union type like this

```
type ValueTypes = "boolean" | "number" | "other"

type ValueRepresents = ({
    [K in ValueTypes]: Partial<Record<Exclude<ValueTypes, K>, false>> & Record<K, true>
})[ValueTypes]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

---

### TL;DR

I don't think this expression has a specific name. I've seen similar examples used in [the docs in Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), but I'll try to explain how it works.

```
type ValueRepresents = {
    [K in ValueTypes]: Partial<Record<Exclude<ValueTypes, K>, false>> & Record<K, true>
}
```

creates type equivalent to:

```
type ValueRepresents = {
  boolean: {
    boolean: true;
    number?: false;
    other?: false;
  };
  number: {
    boolean?: false;
    number: true;
    other?: false;
  };
  other: {
    boolean?: false;
    number?: true;
    other: true;
  };
};
```

and by adding the union type in square brackets `[ValueTypes]` it extracts the values of those (all) keys in another union type equivalent to:

```
type ValueRepresents =
  | {
      boolean: true;
      number?: false;
      other?: false;
    }
  | {
      boolean?: false;
      number: true;
      other?: false;
    }
  | {
      boolean?: false;
      number?: true;
      other: true;
    };
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thank you.  I've never seen this syntax before `)[ValueTypes]`, could you point me to some docs explaining it please?  I played around with it now so I have a partial feel for what it's doing but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: @AJP I've added short explanation on how it works