# How can I bind two types together in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want TypeScript to know that when the getData function receives `'myString'` as an argument, it's returning a `Promise<string>`, and when it receives `'myNumber'`, it's returning a `Promise<number>`. I thought this approach would work, but it's giving me errors as shown below. It's not binding `endpoint: 'myString'` to `returnType: string`. What do I need to change?

```js
type MyStringType = { endpoint: 'myString'; returnType: string };
type MyNumberType = { endpoint: 'myNumber'; returnType: number };

function getData<T extends MyStringType | MyNumberType>(endpoint: T['endpoint']) {
  return axios.get<T['returnType']>(`https://my.url/${endpoint}`);
}

getData('myString').then(response => {
  const newString: string = response.data; // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
});

getData('myNumber').then(response => {
  const newNumber: number = response.data; // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
});
```

Comment: You have only two type? `string and numgber`? or you are looking for a general solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `MyStringType | MyNumberType` seems to be inferred by default. You probably don't want this.

Aside from function overloading, or using some kind of [XOR type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732314/a-generic-typescript-interface-with-method-that-returns-exactly-one-of-union-typ/68732916#68732916), you can define a type like so:

```
type EndpointReturnTypes = {
  'myString': string,
  'myNumber': number,
}
```

and then this works

```
async function getData<T extends keyof EndpointReturnTypes>(endpoint: T) {
  return axios.get<EndpointReturnTypes[T]>(endpoint)
}

getData('myString').then(response => {
  const newString: string = response.data;
});

getData('myNumber').then(response => {
  const newNumber: number = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to narrow the members of a union based on a discriminant:

```
function getData<T extends MyStringType|MyNumberType, E extends T["endpoint"]>(endpoint: E) {
  return axios.get<Extract<T, { endpoint: E }>["returnType"]>(`https://my.url/${endpoint}`);
}
```

Now, at the call site of `getData()` the generic `E` will be reified, which allows `Extract` to narrow the union `T` inside the function body, and then use `"returnType"` to index whichever type(s) remain.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3AFAwCeYApnALJUDKMUwAdgOYAqN9AXjgBvOLQ4ATSJxgAuOAHIQLNpy4LScKLRgBXKBz515aVdzgBfCtTqMqAOV0gARrShHBIsZOkc5i5UcXNw0tHX1DfnkOJ1coSwpyTF0OAGMYVA44Lh0AEQQYBAAeHjEkGHEJDCZWdm4PAB8mILiPABo4AFEyiskMHgBtfErfGHwAXQA+AAoRiBl5ToBKEXI4ML0DRBR0ADocmCLO8qgEdJKO0TmFrstJoe1NyLoJmYADAAsYGDA0WQB6f7KXb6AA2-wAJMJrn4LG8lhQLORyAd8oVpkoVHV1EtdjAPuJpto0JAOGhBJNVutUhAyfAOLQAO61NQmMxcOBCYmk8m7CQFBCIhHI1ECjGBWIhXH4wnc2nkzmU4RrOA0ulwBmMlpuaKS+Jc2gk+W0PkCoWkIA)