# Can I specify a recursive property rule based on whether or not it is present in a descendant?

Tags: typescript, types, hl7-fhir

I want to specify a type called `Item` which has the possibility of being nested as follows:

Either

```
type Item {
    ...;
    item: Item;
    answer: {
        ...;
        //(does not contain property "item")
        }
    }
```

OR

```
type Item {
    ...;
    //(does not contain property "item")
    answer: {
        ...;
        item: Item
        }
    }
```

i.e. either the `Item` type can have `item:Item` as a direct child property, or as a grandchild below the property `answer` but not both.

Context: I'm trying to implement the [item property of the QuestionnaireResponse resource from the FHIR specification](http://hl7.org/fhir/stu3/questionnaireresponse.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
type FirstOrSecondLayer<T, I, A extends string> = XOR<T & I, T & Record<A, I>>

type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

type Item = Expand<FirstOrSecondLayer<{
    a: string
    b: string
    answer: {
      c: string
    }
  },{
    item: Item
  }, "answer">
>
```

There is a lot of stuff going on here. I added some extra properties `a`, `b` and `c` for demonstration purposes. You pass the type **without** `item` as `T`. `I` is the exclusive object type. And for `A` you pass the name of the property which nests `I`.

I used the `Expand` type from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/8613630) and `XOR` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types).

Here are some test cases:

```
const t1: Item = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
  item: {} as Item,
  answer: {
    c: ""
  }
} // works

const t2: Item = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
  answer: {
    c: "",
    item: {} as Item,
  }
} // works


const t3: Item = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
  item: {} as Item,
  answer: {
    c: "",
    item: {} as Item, // error
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for your use case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=11&pln=21&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgSwE4GcQHkkGUoGMD2AdgCYAyAhmFEgDwAqANDAJJMCCMUAHiFCSjDRIEhAOYA%20GAF4YADXQAlejABkLJnVUwFefEmI02TZuPHBQkWAFEuEciXqSZm7r34wRAM2ox0MAPwwAN4wANoA0h6EMADWUGD4nr4AugBcvhHJMAC%20MOmEUABu1ADc5uDQMADqCCAAFvgAriD0TACqTsFhAApRMDa4ADaNxFA0cQlJjLHxiTAdyf75RT7ZZRWw8krTHdIwABSaAD7zAJScPHzEAvgARgBWeCABBzX1TS07kmpt5yf7bwazRobQ03xgdHO6WO8zKFkqzF4AFs9jY7A5EKgMNhdCQKFRaEFgDASTByOkhCJRMTSbcKSBhGIaST7CgAO7UdJE0mk3D0xnUnnZGnZBjc0m1KBI9KIqUipgAIlZHKQCrMZnMBEIaBgIAAjDLkXtxeSYAqFQwaXSzRaaZLpcFcuQBLKkZaWdqVVzmTA%20TaRcBcgB6IMwNl6GIoTVEHUgABMhqlxpppvN7pg1rTKc9nOCPr9WZ59q5TpdyPTwuDofDSEj5mAWtjAGZEyiZCb0oWM53bSTi46yWWpenlbnxSSC72JciS4OWOWA1XOEgkHogA)

Comment: It works! I don't understand it yet, I'm going to need to read and experiment with each of the building blocks, but this is amazing. Thank you! ️