# Interface value depending on other optional interface value

Tags: typescript

I have this kind of interface

```
export interface IButton {
 label: string;
 withIcon?: boolean;
 underlined?: boolean;
 selected?: boolean;
 iconName?: string;
 isLink?: boolean;
 href?: string;
 onCLick?: () => void;
}
```

Is it possible to make conditionally the use of iconName based on the use of withIcon ?

To make an example:

`<Button label='test' />` ---> this should not throw error

`<Button withIcon />` this should throw an error that alert me that iconName is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating Union type of icon options as follows:

```
type IconOptions = { withIcon?: false; iconName?: string; } | { withIcon: true; iconName: string; }
```

What this means is that when `withIcon` is true, `iconName` will be required, otherwise it is not required.

You can then append this type as an intersection to `IButton` which will also need to be a type:

```
export type IButton = {
 label: string;
 underlined?: boolean;
 selected?: boolean;
 isLink?: boolean;
 href?: string;
 onCLick?: () => void;
} & IconOptions;
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYHkzAJbIM5QLxQDeUA7hsABbzID8AXFAGYCGANthANxQaJIByzALYR6UbMABOGJAHNOAXygAfIqXJU+DKQFcuPPoJEMJ0udwUAoSxAAeYBJOBRQkWACEdwYMnxFLUKzMAEYQrCZSMvIBOkgAJhCSrDIQcWLBCAisEMxInAEc2XDAqemZ2bn5PNgAMjIA1mVZOXkBFJIQjGKmUVXIAMJ1cI0MABQAlPgAfFAAbggYcflKAGSwfGiYOPmWfBJQwV4+SAwwnt6+BIQBULdBoeFQAOTM2HGvzE8ANDe3ZJTUE5MNgcH4KIA).

Comment: This still allows for `{iconName:"foo", withIcon:false}`. A union of `{ withIcon : false }|{ withIcon: true; iconName: string; }` would be a better model (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: I wrote this answer based on the type that was provided on the example question. That's what I actually had it as initially, but I'm not sure how OP prefers it.

Comment: On a second thought, OP did set it to optional because they didn't want it to always be there, so it makes sense for ```iconName``` not to be there when ```withIcon``` does not exist or is false.

Comment: There is a problem: if i try to use type IconOptions = { withIcon?: false; } | { withIcon: true; iconName: string; }, typescript throw me an error in the component. 

(parameter) iconName: any
Property 'iconName' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<PropsWithChildren<IButton>>'

Comment: Can you try changing ```IconOptions``` to the following and see if it fixes your issue: ```type IconOptions = { withIcon?: false; iconName?: string } | { withIcon: true; iconName: string; }```

Comment: Yup, it fixes in this way. I think that without iconName?: string into the first type typescript goes in rage mode because iconName doesn't exists from its point of view.

Comment: Good to hear it helped, I have updated my answer :)

Comment: @Legeo With a union of  `{ withIcon? : false }|{ withIcon: true; iconName: string; }`, you have a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) (the discriminator is the `withIcon` prop). If you test the discriminator, the type will be appropriately narrowed and you will consequently be able to use the `iconName` property. So, for instance `const iconName = props.withIcon ? props.iconName : undefined` will work without inciting TypeScript's "rage mode"

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be similar to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42123407/8613630).

You can solve it by creating a union of both possible cases.

```
export type IButton = {
 label: string;
 underlined?: boolean;
 selected?: boolean;
 isLink?: boolean;
 href?: string;
 onCLick?: () => void;
} & ({
 iconName: string;
 withIcon: true
} | {
 iconName?: never;
 withIcon?: never | false
})
```

This will throw an error if one property is used without the other.

```
function main(){
  return (
    <>
      <Button label="abc"></Button> // valid
      <Button label="abc" iconName="abc" withIcon></Button> // valid
      <Button label="abc" withIcon></Button> // error: Property 'iconName' is missing in type
      <Button label="abc" iconName="abc"></Button> // error: Property 'iconName' is missing in type
      <Button label="abc" withIcon={false} iconName="abc"></Button> // error: Types of property 'iconName' are incompatible
    </>
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=5&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSkAPSWOGATzCTgEkAhAVxhggDs4AvHADepOABsUAIyTiAXHADOMKMF4BzANykAvnABkcABSi4wNHwByKEEgXLVG7XADuwGAAsWF3gpUckXTgAHxExcysbJAB+BV4kADckKGc3T28+WLh4pKgQuEwUcUVAnQBKch9lOE5uPkFjMBwwRQV2Lh5eMsEAPjC4OCIYDih+AB4AE2AEnrGAeimZ3XJMDl4MYHqQFDUjMtNBpGHR4zEBuDGes-OL2s6JaVkBfGk0fFm5u74+ubm4BKKwAm13OYy+-EkMnEz1e+DMPmsthhUjerncXh8H3BPz+APEQJBAzBHXqkKeLxRcLSGO+82xcF+cGSOCgCgACs1kgw4AByCK8RFIHlmRRwEDARSKNTqMz8BhMQm3EkQx7Qimo-mC5FvLHKnFMqAs9mc2D0XmaqLCiViiVSjSyuiMQI3eZXAYVHRAA)