# How to enforce a discriminated union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type UrlCellRendererProps = {
    prop1: string;
};

type GroupByCellRendererProps = {
    prop2: boolean;
    prop3: number;
};

type TEST = UrlCellRendererProps | (UrlCellRendererProps & GroupByCellRendererProps)

// this is valid
const a: TEST = {
    prop1: 'url',
}

// this is valid
const b: TEST = {
    prop1: 'url',
    prop2: true,
    prop3: 13
}

// this should be invalid because prop3 is missing
const c: TEST = {
    prop1: 'url',
    prop2: true,
}

console.log(a)
```

in the example above I have a create a type called `TEST` which is a union type of two types. How can I enforce the type so that either (`prop1` is required) OR (`prop1` AND `prop2` AND `prop3` are required)

Comment: Your last example is valid because it matches `UrlCellRendererProps` by itself. Having an extra property called `prop2` doesn't mean it doesn't match that type.

Comment: You can fix this using an exclusive OR . Look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types. I have created a TS playground to test this : https://cutt.ly/LKS6Wl3

Comment: The first comment is completely accurate though

Comment: @TusharShahi wow that was exactly what I was looking for. I still could not understand the cause for this behavior of TypeScript. Why would the default union TS behave like this?