# How to define a function with an object with multiple entries as an argument, that only accepts one entry?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Imagine a function that get an object as argument that has two entries with any possible type.

```
const x = ({a,b}:{a: string, b: string}) => {
    // return something
}

x({a: "foo"}) // OK
x({b: "bar"}) // OK
x({a: "foo", b: "bar"}) // get a compile error in this case!
```

How can we set this function in a way that only one of the entries be passed to function? In other words, I need to get a compile error when both entries are set inside the function?
For example, if "a" is already passed, the moment "b" is also passed we get a compilation error and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

My original intuitive, and obviously **wrong**, answer: Use a **union type**:

```js
{ a: string } | { b: string }
```

This will **not** trigger a compile error for `x({a: "foo", b: "bar"})`.

Working solution: You can follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229567) for “mutually exclusive types”:

```js
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

const x = (args: XOR<{ a: string }, { b: string }>) => {
    // return something
}

x({a: "foo"}) // OK
x({b: "bar"}) // OK
x({a: "foo", b: "bar"}) // get a compile error in this case!
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7ADwBUA0UCqAfFALxQDeUA2gApRwB2UAogB4DGANqgCYQYBrCCGQAzKLihCR4ogF0A-AC4oDCADcIAJygBfANwAoUJCgANAPIAlbHiKkoACixQAPgQCUUCK2AQGPADOUMgARgBWEOzAUApO8EhomJL2AGSebvEIKOgY+HhYxOlYXiou7vhGhuzIDIExrA6OAIZaAOaBKpY2lM0q9VqMbXp4lKH9wIMMw7qEXiTE5IZQK1AA9GtQWhDAqFpMgcgAtjuIQ4a6hoasjuR9UABEosjID7peG1AWANLXt+OPUKtN4fTY-P53FRPF4PPAAh5ArQg9abNo7KDNKA1I5gOCcaDaLTIHSMKBIODBdjNQIQACEhiAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it works almost perfect. However, there is one small issue, if we pass 'b' as first entry ( for example: ``` x({b: "foo", a: "bar"}) ``` ), we get a compile error for "b" again, but we should get it for "a" this time.

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert in this field, but I doubt that you can influence this behavior.