# Is it possible to annotate exclusive union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find a type for generic error handling that does something like this:

```
function request(): GenericError<{body:string}> {
  if (/* Some condition */) {
    return { error: "An error occurred" };
  }

  return { body: "Things went well" };
}
```

The goal is to infer that `body` exists if `error` doesn't, i.e:

```
const response = request();

if (response.error) return;

/* TypeScript should infer that body can't be undefined here */
```

I don't know if this is possible in TypeScript and this question might be a duplicate, but I don't know how to word the problem exactly. I tried annotating the function with the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) but none of them could guarantee `body` to exist if `error` didn't, as far as I could see.

---

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQCcCmBHCmDOcAFAJQBcqA3puukuhYeglAOYC+qAPlQEZIATAJ6M4zNp0qhUqBGFREAsgEM4ACwB06ZVAFIAtqRJVpMjJjgR0aSqhp0GqAEQBBNPfqokMGFawCnVHYAblN2UFMsS2sqVH5hCicAFTUWVnxUAHdMKDgszAAbAsCQ0HCQUEhYRBRUPRS0-FITEBkYFEJzfAAHDsxUAF5zXAJiElCK1tl5Iiwevo0PdGMoqygJ0wB6ACpUJKFuzABlGGZuvPw1JAgCgVkoMBpUdVU4wSFUGB0AcjzefugAkwYBYmDuaho-W2mwiU02m1QAAU6Id0HAPt94kJvnUkARUFAkHlMAAPBCdWrow6ob62JaicSsYJBbixLEMtLM9jfDRbBEyZFIVHomlYnF6fGE4lkiloKn9Wl2Wj0DlsLk8yIEXpQfCYDRYiblIA)

Comment: Why you don't just return union between body and error? The  you can check with in operator if error is in response.

Comment: Why not `{ body: string } | {error: string}` ??

Comment: @KiraLT Using that union errors when doing if (response.error), complaining that response.error in undefined in { body: string }.

Comment: A discriminated union with an indicator of success seems like a good option here.

Comment: You could use the union and change the condition from `response.error` to `"error" in response`.

Comment: Yep narrowing is the way to go !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union `{ error: string } | { body: string }` + narrowing will do it :

```
function request(): { error: string } | { body: string } {
    if (/* Some condition */) {
        return { error: "An error occurred" };
    }

    return { body: "Things went well" };
}

const response = request();

if ('error' in response) { // narrowing
    response.error // OK
    return 
}

response.body // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=25&pln=13&pc=12#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYEcSoM5QBQCUAXIgN6KrLJzIm7IxgDmiAvogD5mIBGcAJgE86UBszZkAUIhmIYwRHgD0AKkQBlOAFtUiCAn4xYCRCqUEpsqylRQQyJOUrVaiAEQBBJM5qI4ECHs0fjc2AG5pWVZJSJk0OwduPiESNwAVAAtGJmxEAHdUMCh81AAbUtDWCOjJfTBcG2wABwRsXQBeG0wcfAIIyXlFAHIfZCG5JDRm1tQLUljGlvrUADpRxCUlRAB5AGkF%20PskSRqppbaV5MENrb3ESSA)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this pattern than uses a discriminated union alongside a "success" property:

```
interface SuccessResult {
    result: true;
    body: string;
}
interface FailureResult {
    result: false;
    error: string;
}
type Result = SuccessResult | FailureResult;
```

Now change the original function to return this instead:

```
function request(): Result {
    if (/* Some condition */) {
        return { result: false, error: "An error occurred" };
    }

    return { result: true, body: "Things went well" };
}
```

And finally check for the outcome in the caller:

```
const response = request();
if (response.result) {
    //Read response.body here, with response.error being invalid (won't compile)
} else {
    //Read response.error here, with response.body being invalid (won't compile)
}
```