# React Typescript Props Validation; How to validate 2 props items not existing at the same time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am working on a reusable component in React-Typescript. I need to validate my props **OnClick** and **component** as

1. Both onClick and component prop are optional. I would pass these props to component only  if I need them to be configured as such.
2. Both of them shall not be passed to the component at the same time. ie, if I am passing in **onClick** then **component** prop shall not be passed in. Likewise if I am passing in  **component** then **onClick** prop shall not be passed in.

I tried different combinations; This is the best possible scenario I reached;

```
interface Common {
   /** common items **/
} 
interface WithOnClick extends Common {
   onClick: () => void;
   component: never;
}
interface WithComponent extends Common {
   onCick: never;
   component: React.ReactElement<HTMLElement>
}
interface Main = WithComponent | WithOnClick | Common;
```

But this was still causing issues cause It was always resolving to **Common**;

Is there any possible way to define type for my scenario. Or am I doing something totaly wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`XOR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) type.

```
type XOR<T, U> = T | U extends object
  ?
      | ({ [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never } & U)
      | ({ [P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]?: never } & T)
  : T | U;
```

So your interfaces will become

```
interface WithOnClick extends Common {
   onClick: () => void;
}
interface WithComponent extends Common {
   component: React.ReactElement<HTMLElement>
}
```

> Both onClick and component prop are optional.

You can play a bit with the type for this