# Use typescript to define set of non-compatible react props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I have made a component `MyComponent` with react. I would like to define the props for this component.

Usually i do it like

```js
type Props = {
  foo: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => ...
```

---

Here are the props i would like to always be available

```
selected: string <-- required
onSelect(): void <-- required
margin?: string <-- optional
```

And the following are two sets that are non-compatible, ie. only one of them can be used.

Set one:

```
compact?: boolean <-- optional
minWidth?: number <-- optional
maxWidth?: number <-- optional
```

Set two:

```
width?: number <-- optional
```

---

What is the best way to define these props so that it makes the most sense to the developer using the component? I.e, what gives the best *intellisense* experience?

Comment: Maybe dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types

Answer (score 2):

You can create a XOR-like behavior by using `never`:

```
type Props = {
    selected: string;
    onSelect(): void;
    margin?: string;
} & (
    | {
          compact?: boolean;
          minWidth?: number;
          maxWidth?: number;
          width?: never;
      }
    | {
          compact?: never;
          minWidth?: never;
          maxWidth?: never;
          width?: number;
      }
);
```

Then when you give it invalid props:

```
<MyComponent selected="foo" onSelect={() => {}} margin="0" width={0} compact={true} />
```

You'll get a fairly helpful error:

> Type '{ selected: string; onSelect: () => void; margin: string; width: number; compact: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Type '{ selected: string; onSelect: () => void; margin: string; width: number; compact: true; }' is not assignable to type '{ compact?: undefined; minWidth?: undefined; maxWidth?: undefined; width?: number | undefined; }'.
> Types of property 'compact' are incompatible.
> Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVbEBN)