# Multiple mutually exclusive parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Given the following JavaScript function:

```js
function x({foo, fooId, bar, barId}) {}
```

I want to convert it to TypeScript so that the caller must pass in either
`foo` or `fooId`, but not both. Likewise for `bar` and `barId`.

For example, `x({foo: "", bar: ""})` and  `x({fooId: "", bar: ""})` would be allowed function calls, but the compiler would prevent `x({foo: "", fooId: "", bar: ""})` and `x({bar: ""})`.

Is this possible with the TypeScript type system and how to do it?

Comment: By "_mutually exclusive_", do you mean you require at least one of them to be present?

Comment: Yes. So it'll prevent `x({foo: "", fooId: "", bar: ""})` and `x({bar: ""})` but allow `x({foo: "", bar: ""})` and  `x({fooId: "", bar: ""})`. Likewise for bar and barId.

Comment: "Mutually exclusive" does not, by itself, imply that one must appear, so you should say something like "exactly one of the properties `foo` and `fooId` should appear" instead

Comment: What types do you want for these properties?  I guess `any`?

Comment: The type of the properties doesn't matter that much. In the project where I have this use case, the ID variable is a string and it'll cause a React component to fetch the object over the network. The non-ID variable is the object itself and that's used in tests to pass in test data.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK9RDN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it (although it might be a duplicate).  If not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that seems to work. Please write it up as an answer and explain that how it works.

Comment: May be related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you're looking for is this:

```
type XArgs = 
 { foo: any; fooId?: never; bar: any; barId?: never; } |
 { foo: any; fooId?: never; barId: any; bar?: never; } | 
 { fooId: any; foo?: never; bar: any; barId?: never; } | 
 { fooId: any; foo?: never; barId: any; bar?: never; };
      
function x({ foo, fooId, bar, barId }: XArgs) { }

x({ foo: "", bar: "" }); // okay
x({ fooId: "", bar: "" }); // okay
x({ foo: "", fooId: "", bar: "" }); // error
x({ bar: "" }); // error
```

So `XArgs` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with four possibilities. Let's look at the first one:

```
{ foo: any; fooId?: never; bar: any; barId?: never }
```

So `foo` and `bar` are properties of type `any`, so they must be present.  But `fooId` and `barId` are [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) (signified by `?`) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  There are no values of the `never` type, so you can't actually supply a defined `fooId` or `barId` property there... and since optional properties may be omitted, then an optional property of type `never` is essentially prohibited.  So that type means that `foo` and `bar` are required, and `fooId` and `barId` are prohibited.

The other three union members are similar, except different properties are accepted and prohibited.  Together, the four union members of type `XArgs` describe the full range of allowable arguments to `x()`.

So that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

But it could be prohibitively tedious to write out the necessary union manually, especially if you have more than two members of your [*exclusive unions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (where you want exactly one element to appear), or more than two sets of properties you care about.

If so, you can have the compiler compute `XArgs` as follows:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never
type ExclusiveUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> = 
  T extends unknown ? (T & { [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never }) : never;
```

The `AllKeys<T>` type is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that computes the union of [the keys of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) each union member of `T`, so `AllKeys<{a: 0} | {b: 1}>` is `"a" | "b"`.

Then `ExclusiveUnion<T>` type is another distributive conditional type  that takes a union like `{a: string} | {b: number} | {c: boolean}` and produces an exclusive version where each member explicitly prohibits members that only appear in other members.  (It uses `AllKeys` to get the keys of the other members.)  It would be the equivalent of `{a: string, b?: never, c?: never} | {a?: never, b: number, c?: never} | {a?: never, b?: never, c: boolean}`.

Notice I said "equivalent"; you actually get unions of [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), like `{a: string} & {b?: never, c?: never}`, which can get unwieldy.

So I have an `Expand<T>` [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that collapses intersections while it expands any other aliased properties:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } : T;
```

And then we define `XArgs` as an intersection of `ExclusiveUnion`s, and `Expand` it so that it's pretty:

```
type XArgs = Expand<
  ExclusiveUnion<{ foo: any } | { fooId: any }> &
  ExclusiveUnion<{ bar: any } | { barId: any }>
>;
```

which is exactly

```
type XArgs = 
 { foo: any; fooId?: never; bar: any; barId?: never; } |
 { foo: any; fooId?: never; barId: any; bar?: never; } | 
 { fooId: any; foo?: never; bar: any; barId?: never; } | 
 { fooId: any; foo?: never; barId: any; bar?: never; };
```

Let's try it on a type that's harder to write out by hand:

```
type YArgs = Expand<
  ExclusiveUnion<{ a: 0 } | { b: 1 } | { c: 2 }> &
  ExclusiveUnion<{ x: 9 } | { y: 8 } | { z: 7 }>
>
/* type YArgs = 
  { a: 0, b?: never, c?: never, x: 9, y?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { a: 0, b?: never, c?: never, y: 8, x?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { a: 0, b?: never, c?: never, z: 7, x?: never, y?: never; } | 
  { b: 1, a?: never, c?: never, x: 9, y?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { b: 1, a?: never, c?: never, y: 8, x?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { b: 1, a?: never, c?: never, z: 7, x?: never, y?: never; } | 
  { c: 2, a?: never, b?: never, x: 9, y?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { c: 2, a?: never, b?: never, y: 8, x?: never, z?: never; } | 
  { c: 2, a?: never, b?: never, z: 7, x?: never, y?: never; } */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=23&ssc=27&pln=22&pc=25#code/PQKgBALgngDgpmAGgQQE4HMDOYC8YCwAUGAN5gBmA9pQFxgCGAdlANwXUCSAJgPx2NwAbnFRsARvVR0mrMBNTc+YAcNFgAvmAA+RUu1oNmbKpUX8hI8ZO7SjcyUpWWN2gsTImbh2SccW18ray8mbK-myaWm56nlxBxtR+qlYKcd4pSc6aIMBEeYTQ8GDIADYlANJwUJgAPAAqAHy4YHVgcAAeEHCMXNgArowA1oyUAO6MYDxgg1WU5C1g5qpEhQgAou0AxiV9mACWwgCqjHuUjPUANGDlbZ3dvWAACqiU8KjQlVDNpRVVtY1NPCtDpdHr9IYjcaTXRgAAUrQAZHoANqPMB7CYbbZ9LhwGrlK4zKBzFoNAC6mVQGgAlIswsl8qswBsYEwuPVAQsQfdsJQxAArOCbCCTFE3DHTWbzOpkugstn1ZHlMlNTR0OosRmwBAoDDYPDyno1GFYnb7I4nM41DzUIIuKI20xpGQaJoIk1bM0HODHU7nMiBbz2vQhZ3MV1EBqawj5cgDYV+sDtWGOq6xK7yDPWLgaOi6rC0sjqfLJx10ABE5azUjAlZp0dL+i8lerFfL9aIjZMbbTnDSLfsNbr6mpDZTg7bHZj06ZAE00Fhmob2R7seafZb-Qw6AAGYMBugARn3YE2dAATK6wO7iMzPbtvb6rWR2nQAJwnqB0AAcJ4AXnQADsEaEA0RCgJA2pgPOerNDCZD0LuGaUlcmwoUm75XFA6F-pSESuPB25gDuyFLCIqHoV+YDflc7Q4XhwaEYhxGkfS5GnjhQG0ZRDGRNEIZHlc9DoWhZGoLRmFgNhYlXLhYn4VEhFiIJDAiZRP7cTJYByWxah8UpKnCVpom6bJXFJjx8mMbeZBnmA55CehYjoa+YBvlh9FWfpNmnhejlac5WlUTRFlaTpTh6QRPl2Q5qkBZxYCAZpplSbxYA5EQQA)

Comment: Thanks. That's a very thorough explanation. It's teaching me lots about TS. ChatGPT's answers can't even compare: https://twitter.com/EskoLuontola/status/1599937038299824128