# Typescript: union object key

Tags: typescript

I wanna do something like

```
type ObjectType = {
  'a' | 'b': number;
};

const obj1: ObjectType = { a: 0} // <- good  
const obj2: ObjectType = { b: 0} // <- good  
const obj3: ObjectType = { a: 0, b: 1 } // <- bad  

/// or 

type Union = 'a' | 'b';
type ObjectType = {
  [Union]: number;
};

const obj1: ObjectType = { a: 0} // <- good  
const obj2: ObjectType = { b: 0} // <- good  
const obj3: ObjectType = { a: 0, b: 1 } // <- bad
```

Is it possible to do it?  If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Seems like you're asking about [mutually exclusive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types).

Comment: TS has a nice feature which is called [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) . See [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDDZjN) example.