# TypeScript: how to only allow certain combinations of keys in object?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I'd like to define an object type that represents an inequality. Something like this:

```js
{ "<": x => Math.sin(x) } // ok, y < sin(x)
{ ">": x => Math.sin(x) } // ok, y > sin(x)
{ ">=": -4, "<": 4 } // ok, -4 <= y < 4
```

But I want to prevent nonsensical combinations, like having both "less than" *and* "less than or equal to":

```js
{ "<": 5, "<=": 5 } // should cause a TypeScript error
```

Is this possible? So far I've tried something that felt obvious: a union.

```js
type Fn = number | ((x: number) => number)

type Inequality =
  | Record<">", Fn>
  | Record<"<", Fn>
  | Record<"<=", Fn>
  | Record<">=", Fn>
  | Record<">" | "<", Fn>
  | Record<">" | "<=", Fn>
  | Record<">=" | "<", Fn>
  | Record<">=" | "<=", Fn>
```

However, with this, TypeScript unions all these types together and allows any combination of these keys. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFOBXAtgIwgJygHygAoiAPALhQ2xwEokA%20KrXWgKDdEigEk4IAjqgCGAGwCWoJGygEoAJQgBjAPY4AJgB4ARA20AaWHAYy5i1Rp07D8E7MLm1W7ZsQGjds8qc6Gbm8amDt6WutpyLu62QQohznoRrlGB9rEW8W6JyZ7B6b6ZhC7%20HhyqcADOwFAqmABWlHyCIhJSyADeprJhlAC0ACz6nVAA9MNQAALA5T0QpJBKwDM4OGpDum69A2wAvkA).

Is it possible to make TypeScript only allow the combinations I declare?

Answer (score 2):

Intersect the members of the union with another record that uses `never`:

```
type Inequality =
  | Record<">", Fn> & Record<">=", never>
  | Record<"<", Fn> & Record<"<=", never>
  | Record<"<=", Fn> & Record<"<", never>
  | Record<">=", Fn> & Record<">", never>
  | Record<">" | "<", Fn> & Record<">=" | "<=", never>
  | Record<">" | "<=", Fn> & Record<">=" | "<", never>
  | Record<">=" | "<", Fn> & Record<">" | "<=", never>
  | Record<">=" | "<=", Fn> & Record<">" | "<", never>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYLkgm)

---

For smaller cases this is alright, but it gets out of hand very quickly and you may need a utility type to generate this union for you from some rules (like ">" and ">=" are mutually exclusive).

You may find [XOR types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types) useful.

Comment: It seems like this only allows single-key objects, and gets a false positive on things like `{ ">": ..., "<": ... }`.

Comment: @StevenPetryk Oh, I think you need to make the `never`'s optional with `Partial`: https://tsplay.dev/N55L2N

Comment: But then it allows all combinations again. What a conundrum!

Comment: @StevenPetryk Really? I tried `>` and `>=` together and it gave me an error. What gives a false negative?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type of the wrong inequalities and then infer if the current object is wrong ( implementation in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFOBXAtgIwgJygHygAoiAPALhQ2xwEokA+KrXWgKA9EigHUcB7OAHMAknAgBHVAEMANgEtg8iAGckUAN4AiBlsrwANFB2I9sOAF8CmrQB4zh47dP7LAbk7hoYyTIWgkNihrACUIAGN+HAATe10jeAYg0Iio2LstBLgk4MIwyJj7Z0zzHJSC9IZTLLK81MKdLWsMmuS6irimwjtq0raofLS402b7VtyB+sqR7uLx6z5BUXEpOUVlFQ5IuBVgKH5MACtKH1X-EGDkDWTgxsoAWgAWAxvjKrMnl4tPbgBRUkg4WAtgAKlAIKRgBA4NE1MAcKgIExkCCOD9vCoAGpraKnPyKECg8GQ6GwqB4tagZFQMEQqEwtSLYQU-wbKAAfigADM5CpoJR4Yj0TT1P9AcCRFicSyCbYuBB+Fz9kcGEwAPRqqAAd3kslkUGw4JwAhwEGiQA)

But to be honest you'd be better doing some checks in a function , there are other runtime cases that cannot be covered, like for exemple `{">": 4, ">=": 3}` is a valid inequality , or `{">": 0, "<": -1}` is wrong inequality