# Typescript allow only one property

Tags: typescript, types, interface, react-functional-component

This code allow me to send in props just one of the options but not the other, for example:

```
<Drawer volunteer />
```

now it's 3 properties, but if there is more how can i write it more generic ?

The Drawer types declaration:

```
type DrawerTypes =
    { volunteer: boolean } & { rescues?: never } & { map?: never } |
    { volunteer?: never } & { rescues: boolean } & { map?: never } |
    { volunteer?: never } & { rescues?: never } & { map: boolean };
```

Comment: Does [this previous answer about mutually-exclusive types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229567/21146235) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map over the keys, picking the specific key and making the others `never`:

```
type OneOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>>;
}[keyof T]
```

The new definition of `DrawerTypes` would be

```
type DrawerTypes = OneOf<{ volunteer: boolean; rescues: boolean; map: boolean }>;
```

Admittedly, the tooltip of `DrawerTypes` is not particularly helpful, so if you add this extra bit,

```
type OneOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>>;
}[keyof T] extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

you can see that `DrawerTypes` is equivalent to

```
type DrawerTypes = {
    volunteer: boolean;
    rescues?: undefined;
    map?: undefined;
} | {
    rescues: boolean;
    volunteer?: undefined;
    map?: undefined;
} | {
    map: boolean;
    volunteer?: undefined;
    rescues?: undefined;
}
```

which is the same as your original definition of `DrawerTypes`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAzAPAFQHxQLxQN4CwAUFKVANoDSUAlnFANYQgD2SUaAugFxQAKNAMYN0AGiiUsAMn4BDAE7AasgDYoAShEEt5AExQBRAB6CVAV10QUTVuzTjJ4hADcI8jBgDcxAL7kbbBycUBBGwBBwugDOtHBIbrBQAPz4FNR0jMyBMDywVME+ULwubt5ExKCQUAAi8rIA7m5o4BAxuPCIqHhQzizmcOFuvABGLH0QsnCeUPKtgmatI2MqE1NQALayYEvjk1A+XsTESGZwgkos9LUNbgAUYPIsYFG8143yzZBRAJT4R0Q+IA)

---

note: `key?: undefined` is equivalent to `key?: never` without `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.