# Typescript: Why class and object union got merged

Tags: typescript

How can i create union type of class or interface

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgRmgbwFDWgNzBAFdkAuaCAFwCcBLAOwHNoAfC+AWwCMB7EAbiw5owHvSrUiwSj2oAKAsTIUaDZmwideIAJSZhuSgAtaEAHSKS0ALz5CJQbgC+WF1gaVk1AGZhgyOCRkACZ9XHowDmUJNUdoIghlXj5kMHpBN0oguB4Aa2R6GxU6JlZAlHQ2BBRgwSxRcUpoGXz6clg8gqLscMjlACIWgv6AGmEE5RoSMdxLAbn+134gA)

```
class Type1 {
  value: string | symbol;

  constructor(value: string | symbol) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

interface Type2 {
  name: string;
  use: boolean;
}

type Token = string | Type1 | Type2;

const token: Token = {
  name: "token",
  use: true,
  value: "value"
};
```

if Type2 has only name and use prop why i can also declare value ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does TypeScript support mutually exclusive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types)

Comment: sorry no, its only making other props optional.

Comment: Unions are not exclusive and object types are not sealed.  You can write a utility type to make unions of object types behave more like exclusive unions, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPOREm). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining or find an appropriate dupe target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I will use this approach for my situation `Omit<Type1, "value">`

Comment: I don’t understand how that would work; could you demonstrate somewhere? (e.g., [edit] the question, put an IDE link in a comment, or if it’s a solution post it as an answer)