Define type which is either A or B, not the union/intersection of both
How can I define a type which can be either "A" or "B" but never both?
Example:
type FromSnapshot = {
    snapshotId: string;
};

type NewInstance = {
    version: string;
    storageGB: number;
};

type DatabaseConfig = FromSnapshot | NewInstance;

// Okay.
const fromSnapshot: DatabaseConfig = {
    snapshotId: "123",
};

// Okay.
const newInstance: DatabaseConfig = {
    version: "1.2.3",
    storageGB: 20,
};

// Not okay -- object must specify `snapshotId` OR `version`, `storageGB` -- NEVER BOTH.
const fromSnapshotAndNewInstance: DatabaseConfig = {
    snapshotId: "123",
    version: "1.2.3",
    storageGB: 20,
};

See it n the TS Playground.
Note: The goal is to avoid having to add inverse never properties in each type (e.g. adding snapshotId?: never to the NewInstance type).

a) turn on excess property checks or b) exactly add those never properties c) add a discriminator property

You say you don't want to add never properties so you presumably have already found the question this is a duplicate of.  There's not really any other possibility; either deal with TS's less-than-optimal excess property checking on unions, or add those never properties.

@Anerdw this solution within your linked question did work. Thanks.

This seems like a pretty good case for a discriminated union and branding.
// apply a "brand" so that SnapshotIds and Versions still behave
// like strings, but are distinguishable to the type system
type SnapshotId = string & { __type: 'snapshotId' }
type Version = string & { __type: 'version'

// for the parts of the type that should remain distinct
// introduce a 'type' field with a literal value that varies for each type
type FromSnapshot = {
    __type: 'from-snapshot'
    snapshotId: string;
}

type NewInstance = {
    __type: 'new-instance'
    version: string;
}

type StorageCapacity {
   storageGB: number;
}

type FromSnapshotDBConfig = StorageCapacity & FromSnapshot;

type NewInstanceDBConfig = StorageCapacity & NewInstance;

type DatabaseConfig = FromSnapshotDBConfig | NewInstanceDBConfig

Now DatabaseConfig will accept either of these values:
const fromSnapshotConfig: DatabaseConfig = {
    __type: 'from-snapshot',
    snapshotId: "snapshotId" as SnapshotId,
    storageGB: 100
}

const newInstanceConfig: DatabaseConfig = {
    __type: 'new-instance',
    version: '1.2.3' as Version,
    storageGB: 200
} 

But not this one. The __type field acts as a discriminator to tell the type system which member of the union type this should actually be, and therefore what other fields should be allowed
const typeErrorConfig: DatabaseConfig = {
    __type: 'new-instance',
    version: 'snapshotId' as SnapshotId,
    storageGB: 300
}

To simplify handling of your branded strings, you can make pretty simple factory functions:
const asVersion = (value: string) => value as Version; 

which then lets you write this:
const newInstanceConfig: DatabaseConfig = {
    __type: 'new-instance',
    version: asVersion('1.2.3'),
    storageGB: 200
} 

Or, to simplify it even further, you could create factory methods for the entire config object, which makes setting the __type fields and the brands implicit.
You can do create these factory functions:
const newInstanceDBConfigFactory = ({version, storageGB}: {version: string, storageGB: number}) => ({
    __type: "new-instance", // setting __type in the factory means you don't have to explicitly set it when you use it
    version,
    storageGB
} as NewInstanceDBConfig); // cast to NewInstanceDBConfig handles setting the Version branded string type

const fromSnapshotDBConfigFactory = ({snapshotId, storageGB}: {snapshotId: string, storageGB: number}) => ({
    __type: "from-snapshot",
    snapshotId,
    storageGB
} as FromSnapshotDBConfig); // cast to FromSnapshotDBConfig handles setting the SnapshotId branded string type


and use them like this:
const fromSnapshotConfig: DatabaseConfig = fromSnapshotDBConfigFactory({
    snapshotId: "snapshotId",
    storageGB: 100
})

const newInstanceConfig: DatabaseConfig = newInstanceDBConfigFactory({
    version: '1.2.3',
    storageGB: 200
});

Now all that type-safety goodness is implicit, and saves a lot of boilerplate in your code.
You could even go one step further for simplification, and instead of defining the Config types directly, you could use the return type of your factory functions to define them implicitly.
After all adjustments and optimizations, I end up with something like this:
type SnapshotId = string & {__type: 'SnapshotId'}

type Version = string & {_type: 'Version'}

const newInstanceDBConfigFactory = ({version, storageGB}: {version: string, storageGB: number}) => ({ 
    __type: "new-instance" as const,  // constrain this to be a literal value, so the resulting type will not accept just any string
    version: version as Version,      // make sure to cast to the branded string variant
    storageGB
});

const fromSnapshotDBConfigFactory = ({snapshotId, storageGB}: {snapshotId: string, storageGB: number}) => ({
     __type: "from-snapshot" as const, // constrain to be a literal value
     snapshotId: snapshotId as SnapshotId, // cast to branded string
     storageGB
});

type DatabaseConfig = ReturnType<typeof fromSnapshotDBConfigFactory> | ReturnType<typeof newInstanceDBConfigFactory>

const fromSnapshotConfig: DatabaseConfig = fromSnapshotDBConfigFactory({
    snapshotId: "snapshotId" as SnapshotId,
    storageGB: 100
})

const newInstanceConfig: DatabaseConfig = newInstanceDBConfigFactory({
    version: '1.2.3',
    storageGB: 200
});

and this still produces a TypeError, as expected:
const typeErrorConfig: DatabaseConfig = {
    __type: 'new-instance',
    version: 'snapshotId' as SnapshotId,
    storageGB: 300
}


Thank you for your detailed answer. I ended up using this solution from a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229567/374198

if you do not want to add any discriminator property(for whatever reason), you can use a creator function:
const configCreator = <const T extends DatabaseConfig>
(v: DatabaseConfig extends infer P // setup for distribution
? P extends never // distribute
  ? never 
  : keyof P extends keyof T 
    ? keyof T extends keyof P 
      ? T 
      : 'keys not match' 
    : 'keys not match' 
: never) => { }

const a = configCreator({
    snapshotId: "123",
    version: "1.2.3",
    storageGB: 20,
}) // error

const b = configCreator({
    snapshotId: "abc",
}) // ok

const c = configCreator({
    version: "1.2.3",
    storageGB: 20,
}) // ok

playground
drawbacks:

no autocomplete
doesnt work with optional

I have no idea how to archive this without discriminator property and without generic function

Thank you for your answer. I ended up using this solution from a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229567/374198

@JoshM. The solution adds inverse never properties to your type, which you rejected in your question
