# Optional parameters based on conditional types

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types, typescript-conditional-types

Is it possible to make a function have either mandatory or optional parameters based on conditional types in TypeScript?

This is what I've got so far:

```
const foo = <T extends string | number>(
    first: T,
    second: T extends string ? boolean : undefined
) => undefined;

foo('foo', true); // ok, as intended
foo(2, true); // not ok, as intended
foo(2, undefined); // ok, as intended
foo(2); // compiler error! I want this to be ok
```

Comment: Optional parameters are a runtime feature (evaluating & passing the default value), which cannot be affected by the type system.

Comment: You could use a simple overload type instead.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do this in 3.1 using [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)

```
const foo = <T extends string | number>(
  first: T, 
  ...a: (T extends string ? [boolean] : [undefined?])
) => undefined;

foo('foo', true); // ok, as intended
foo(2, true); // not ok, as intended
foo(2, undefined); // ok, as intended
foo(2); // ok
```

But the better way is to use overloads.

```
function foo2(first: string, second: boolean) : undefined
function foo2(first: number, second?: undefined): undefined
function foo2<T>(first: T, second?: boolean): undefined{
  return undefined
}

foo2('foo', true); // ok, as intended
foo2(2, true); // not ok, as intended
foo2(2, undefined); // ok, as intended
foo2(2); // ok
```

Comment: Also you can use `: []` instead of `: [undefined?]` if you actually want to remove the parameter entirely.

Comment: @ProdigySim, Is there any way to do this with overloads in the way you described?

Comment: It's important to note that, when using the solution from the first half of this answer, the `a` parameter is wrapped in an array, which means you need to re-assign via `a[0]` or use with `...a`.

Comment: @Julien Yup, you need to get into the array. This is why simple overloads are usually a better solution

Comment: I'm mostly interested in what @ProdigySim mentioned in the first comment here, which enables conditionally required arguments. Is there any way to get conditionally required arguments via overloads?

Comment: You would just leave the argument off the overload. `function foo2(first: number): undefined;`

Comment: @ProdigySim The original request was that  `undefined` can be passed as a second argument, but if it is, the first argument must be number. This was the requesy in the question, this is why I wrote it as such.

Comment: When I try the overload solution, I get this error: The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.

Comment: This dosent work for interfaces. Any way to make this work for interfaces ?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why do we need to wrap it up into an array ?

Comment: @kidz55. It's a tuple type, so we can have optinality on only one side of the conditional type.

Answer (score 4):

To ensure a `second` argument is *never* provided (even when undefined), you could group both parameters into the the rest statement.

```ts
const bar = <T extends string | number>(
  ...args: (T extends string ? [T, boolean] : [T])
) => undefined;

// Usage

bar('bar', true); // ok, as intended
bar(2, true); // not ok, as intended
bar(2); // ok, as intended
bar(2, undefined); // not ok
```

This is a small adjunct to @titian-cernicova-dragomir's answer.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVGBTAHlbMAEwhmgCcBLMAcxgB8YwBXAWwCNtyA+ACgFgAUDHiVy0AFwwMAGhhCRAOmUBDKbyx4CxUhWp0A-DADa7RABtsKsAF0YU482LY41bEQM2AlEK8puME5ELm5EANxCQgggvADk0bFyUOTM2F5hMAD0mTAgANZyKqTU2sFEUYi8AExJKWkZ2UwgsPmFxWCl7hUxNYHOrmDu6Vk5rTBFMCWEZd3VckEhg0TDjfmRgqCQsOwq5CjomvjTusn6DExsnDwCwjDKirs0EOqHpSdUtDBGxrIwZiCWax2BwYby+fx9YIDdwRQRCHbkOIIxIwZKpFajArjdqdcqCBFzVF1DFNFpYiZTZx4glVEljCkdaZdfG7QkLaHLBo5MDNXJ5IA).

Comment: Hey @robstarbuck
How about the params object?
Here is my code based on your answer. It is fine but the code is not clean
https://tsplay.dev/mALOQN
Could you help me to refactor it? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you explain what you're trying to achieve here? My answer has to do with optional parameters not optional object keys for a single parameter, which is I think what you're looking for?

This might be a help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required/61281828#61281828

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @robstarbuck, to avoid having to consume the arguments as spread arguments, you can use overloading or simply type overriding. As long as the implementation matches the overloaded types, TS seems to use the strictest types it can match.

```
const bar: (<T extends string | number>(
  ...args: (T extends string
    ?  // two arguments
    [T, boolean]
    : // one argument or undefined second argument
    [T] | [T, undefined])
) => string) =
  // implementation without spread args
  <T,>(a: T, b?: boolean) => `${a} ${b}`;

bar('bar', true);  // ok
bar(2, true);      // not ok
bar(2);            // ok
bar(2, undefined); // ok
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4C4YAoA8AVGBTADyjzABMIZokBLMAcxgB8YwBXAWzjyQD50BYAFAwYAOnHI6ENOlyFiZClVp0hIkQH4RAem0woAdxAxJHElAhr1AbWwAaeCBAAbPAjABdKyLS6Y4PBMkOjMwWBAkGFYyPAAzWjxSSjxQMiCQ9nNvGFsPJhz7KJj4sESPAEohcpgAXh5KKBp6apqrP2p2AAdXTLCEKGpwGANqKAALEFZYCE6kNyTJS2EYHDs+BDRCuA00OCdXdxb6gAMAEgBvBABfGAu4K+OAbiEhRCR0AHI3j4dG1jxyo8dHoQABrV7IdAAJl+SH+gPU6j8YBA4XBgje0IRiJxwP86MxMKKpDiCVICL8YKEQA)