# Can I mark the parameter in a TypeScript function to be optional by a special type without question mark?

Tags: typescript

In general I could make a function have an optional argument as:

```
function func1(foo:number, bar?:string) : void {}
```

Now I'd like to make a generic function in which the type of the second argument depends on what the first is:

```
type Magic<T> = T extends SomeCondition ? T : never;

function func1<T>(foo:T, bar:Magic<T>) : void {}
```

Obviously the `Magic` type can't control the `?` mark before `:`.

It could only make the type of the argument `bar` to be `never` under some cases but the argument is always `required`.

Can I make the second argument to be optional by a special type or any other way?

---

UPDATE:

A complete sample:

```
class A {
    public foo:string = ''
}

type Test<T> = T extends A ? number : never

function func<T>(arg1 : T, arg2: Test<T>) {

}

// I want the second argument to be required
// if the first is subtype of class A
func({ foo: 'bar'}, 10); 
// Otherwise I want the second argumtn to be optional
// However, error happens here: `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1`  
func({ other: 'bar'});
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry but I didn't understand what you specified. Do you mean to use the `...` rest arguments?

Comment: It's a link to the function overloads section. I would also have suggested this, but I'm not sure how it works with generics

Comment: @A_A I added an other sample in the post but I'm not sure whether the overload could work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [Optional parameters based on conditional types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318011/optional-parameters-based-on-conditional-types)

Reference - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897

```
class A {
    public foo:string = ''
}

type Test<T> = T extends A ? [number] : [];

function func<T>(arg1 : T, ...arg2: Test<T>) {

}

func({ foo: 'bar'}, 10); 
func({ other: 'bar'});
```