# Generic TypeScript type referencing nested interface types dynamically

Tags: ajax, typescript, openapi, type-inference, typescript-generics

Sorry for the confusing title! I'll try to be as clear as possible here. Given the following interface (generated by `openapi-typescript` as an API definition):

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC+T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5+FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsN+v0GIxsmxODw+ERBCIxG8+KUJvhMKp1GhZooPBiCUpfv96qcTlD9r4oP44adzhEomSoXdkmkMlCXlSpB9gOVhdSan86oCms1WhsuhD6bCoTD4Y0Ai5KJQYMYwHgAAqEIhwAC8cAA1sBjBB0ITiCQnHqDXBjcQALJyIiLc1Wm12h2kADa7qIAF1nfq8AAlYCGMIwY3EkgAHgAKnBQKgkMIyGGvcRFgA+P0Ykihk3h4Pp8NZkA5vMUKYkzTiTBIYwuOAAfiDFbD1drwdoLbkpNodfEBlzwHQyGAwijrrjFyu6ejGfrjfzJsLPuEpYt5crxCHdezwFzZHIHMuXIUQooovFFGDIEV3XD7c7Lj-3b7a1bXtE9BxrataDvK4SEnYMXggl9MEnOBp1neckEXJxKFASBYDgbB73gTAwAQABhTAABsKL9VNDW3K8mzDAAaOAPXo683T3b0SwACkkSk3SYyR1APcQPSEmgADppJbWY4wTDpkzUNMPVLS8OJnXx0MXXs4GDKc9PkoxFKJZTU1U8NKAASnEQ0oE4BAolTVdOWADcDXM4sj1LckCMieADCgajjxNRo-PYCjgEkiiIGkHjR1MjgYJY2SrKwmhQhgQKkDgdA5FKHjAooljyDgETfRcKy4EwMgO2MJwAkoYiyMoiieIAIiYVh2C4XgTSxYR2pY9rZBgIaViZQ5yBcCS4ATKBlnJGhfmYSRtUqhw4HoehOJILk4G4UtUh1ZryKojqutRXqMQG8aRrkcbyUmlkjlm+bFucX5aGAYBaDWygNq2nbSM4MAKMwZBugOo6UhOkizrazqWCu9F+qEQbhtGx7JHeyoVv+wHtrgEGODBiGkChw6+ThlrzqR7q0T6-h0burG0qB4nQfByGIWh6mmvh1qLuRnrUeZkQ7t8SLUHa9mieNPawj546BdpxHLtFpnMRZ4apfHbHPG8Zl-DeowFrxqVVqCAG5eBrnycpmGgA) to see this in action

```typescript
export interface paths {
  '/v1/some-path/:id': {
    get: {
      parameters: {
        query: {
          id: number;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
    post: {
      parameters: {
        body: {
          name: string;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

The above interface `paths` will have many paths identified by a string, each having some methods available which then define the parameters and response type.

I am trying to write a generic `apiCall` function, such that given a path and a method knows the types of the parameters required, and the return type.

This is what I have so far:

```typescript
type Path = keyof paths;
type PathMethods<P extends Path> = keyof paths[P];

type RequestParams<P extends Path, M extends PathMethods<P>> =
  paths[P][M]['parameters'];

type ResponseType<P extends Path, M extends PathMethods<P>> =
  paths[P][M]['responses'][200]['schema'];

export const apiCall = (
  path: Path,
  method: PathMethods<typeof path>,
  params: RequestParams<typeof path, typeof method>
): Promise<ResponseType<typeof path, typeof method>> => {
  const url = path;
  console.log('params', params);

  // method & url are 
  return fetch(url, { method }) as any;
};
```

However this won't work properly and I get the following errors:

1. `paths[P][M]['parameters']['path']` -> `Type '"parameters"' cannot be used to index type 'paths[P][M]'`
   Even though it does work (If I do `type test = RequestParams<'/v1/some-path/:id', 'get'>` then `test` shows the correct type)

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you make sure the code here is a [mcve]?  I have [a few issues](https://tsplay.dev/wEDe3W); one is `'path'` does truly seem like it should be an error here, and I can't reproduce your "`method` becomes type `never` for some reason".  Presumably you want `apiCall` to be a generic function, but I can't see what your problem is for myself.  Also, you might want to split this into multiple questions; your errors 1 and 2 seem related to each other, but 3 is just a different problem you are having with your code.

Comment: I could reduce it a bit but it might remove the main problem -> mainly being that path and method are necessary to determine the response type, while all 3 of them are "generic" in the sense that they are determined by the path.

Problems 1 and 2 are the same, problem 3 might not be a problem -> see the TypeScript playground I added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

After few trials, this is the solution I found.

First, I used a conditional type to define `RequestParams`:

```
type RequestParams<P extends Path, M extends PathMethods<P>> = 
    "parameters" extends keyof paths[P][M] 
        ? paths[P][M]["parameters"]
        : undefined;
```

Because typescript deduces the type of `path` on the fly, the key `parameters` may not exist so we cant use it. The **conditional type** checks this specific case.

The same can be done for `ResponseType` (which will be more verbose) to access the properties typescript is complaining about.

Then, I updated the signature of the function `apiCall`:

```
export const apiCall = <P extends Path, M extends PathMethods<P>>(
  path: P,
  method: M,
  params: RequestParams<P, M>
): Promise<ResponseType<P, M>> => {
    //...
};
```

So now the types `P` and `M` are tied together.

### Bonus

Finally, in case there is no parameter needed, I made the parameter `params` optional using a conditional type once again:

```
export const apiCall = <P extends Path, M extends PathMethods<P>>(
  path: P,
  method: M,
  ...params: RequestParams<P, M> extends undefined ? []: [RequestParams<P, M>]
): Promise<ResponseType<P, M>> => {
    //...
};
```

Here is a working [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC+T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5+FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsNhr4ADZyUGKXTnCJRWZo24JZJpDJQl4TXQfYDlEnmX7-eqnYGtDZdCF02FQmHwxoBFyUSgwYxgPAABUIRDgAF44ABrYDGCDofAikhOPkCuDC4gAWTkREWJAAPIK4KBUEhhGR1UQAHziqUyuUK4gkADagoAuk5efy8AAlYCGMIwYWqDj6w3G4Cm80igA0cA1RpAJrNapFWuIuoNlutEoARFN1GgSDmE0myNLZfK+KQXa6nRrXXAAPwO6tuuu1vOYYMozQ5hviAym4DoZDAYQelU+sKY4AAFS9BpLEeTFtj8fDkZTmu1GcFWfFkirzrb9adtAxlyxtFrL1rtDJ5WvHtAkFgcGwl-gmDACAAwphEURG1Fw3FcYzjJdNwtNMdTNTNLQACkPEVxEFaNJHUWDxA1dCaAAOgI-NZl9f0OiDNRQzXa1QLIQdfBHJAxybOAnVdcQnRIowyK7CiDSo11KAASlQqBOAQKI9V9C4rnnAU+LjfcxWtNEP0ieADCgICJSrRpVPYZE8MRCBpAQ2giNoWMiMEj0aHoeg4EwxY4AAMjgDSgK7PBJFCGANKQOB0DkUoEPc2NyAcndhBGQS4EwMhMCQYwnACShvz-ADEQQnMmFYdguF4EVBBEHNYxzWQYBKlZ9l8KB-FwuB-SgZYcWqcRmEkbkXBiuyUxILE4G4a1UlSn9-0ArKcrYTgeCrIrhEqsq5Bzbr7N-TgwERTBkG6AahpSEb0vG7KWCm-LZqEebSqRFFlrgHrhT6sJdvxIA) with the solution. I added a method `delete` with no params just to test the final use case.

## Sources

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318137/6325822

## Edit

Here the updated [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC+T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5+FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsNhr4ADZyUGKXTnCJRWZo24JZJpDJQl4TXQfYDlEnmX7-eqnYGtDZdCF02FQmHwxr9BiMbJsTg8PhEQQiMRvPilElTdRobFQwWUqTUuqAvos-a+KD+OGnDGXLEKu74x5E-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-6eT5YHBTB2GPxgUp2ckTn-B5ow0cqAWceF-HCYlosoGl2X8QV76aZV+n+RB-hma18UiD1zxvA1Q3nJDU2vOYZHcct2bg2JsJ7Ypz7FZ+2mWDVxmPZELW2ZO-X-YRpHJF5kPxFoYBgFoc2RbFuBral6A4-lhOneVgHU-doVPdZuRfZR42+aUM2hcrq34Jtu2yYdxuleTwG3Y1ju4ChrvI+rkfa5l8f46ppOVZn9WmYz2daCRFFaGX6OSY3hut+dluGbbzXIeP1Bu4N7mC97ou4EFkYLdF4fUzXvXIAA) with on errors.

Also, I saw that Alessio's solution only works for one path which is a bit limitating. The one I suggest has no errors and works for any number of paths.

Comment: Thank you for this contribution! However see @alessio's answer - this still has some TS issues unfortunately :(

Comment: @aurbano here the updated solution : no errors and any number of paths supported

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Just in case anyone is browsing this in the future, `ResponseType` shouldn't use `keyof` if we want it to be the actual response object.

Answer (score 0):

I checked [Baboo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6325822/baboo)'s solution by following the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC%20T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5%20FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsNhr4ADZyUGKXTnCJRWZo24JZJpDJQl4TXQfYDlEnmX7-eqnYGtDZdCF02FQmHwxoBFyUSgwYxgPAABUIRDgAF44ABrYDGCDofAikhOPkCuDC4gAWTkREWJAAPIK4KBUEhhGR1UQAHziqUyuUK4gkADagoAuk5efy8AAlYCGMIwYWqDj6w3G4Cm80igA0cA1RpAJrNapFWuIuoNlutEoARFN1GgSDmE0myNLZfK%20KQXa6nRrXXAAPwO6tuuu1vOYYMozQ5hviAym4DoZDAYQelU%20sKY4AAFS9BpLEeTFtj8fDkZTmu1GcFWfFkirzrb9adtAxlyxtFrL1rtDJ5WvHtAkFgcGwl-gmDACAAwphEURG1Fw3FcYzjJdNwtNMdTNTNLQACkPEVxEFaNJHUWDxA1dCaAAOgI-NZl9f0OiDNRQzXa1QLIQdfBHJAxybOAnVdcQnRIowyK7CiDSo11KAASlQqBOAQKI9V9C4rnnAU%20LjfcxWtNEP0ieADCgICJSrRpVPYZE8MRCBpAQ2giNoWMiMEj0aHoeg4EwxY4AAMjgDSgK7PBJFCGANKQOB0DkUoEPc2NyAcndhBGQS4EwMhMCQYwnACShvz-ADEQQnMmFYdguF4EVBBEHNYxzWQYBKlZ9l8KB-FwuB-SgZYcWqcRmEkbkXBiuyUxILE4G4a1UlSn9-0ArKcrYTgeCrIrhEqsq5Bzbr7N-TgwERTBkG6AahpSEb0vG7KWCm-LZqEebSqRFFlrgHrhT6sJdvxIA) to his TypeScript playground.
At line 57, the `ResponseType` type gives the following error:

```
Type '"responses"' cannot be used to index type 'paths[P][M]'.(2536)
Type '200' cannot be used to index type 'paths[P][M]["responses"]'.(2536)
Type '"schema"' cannot be used to index type 'paths[P][M]["responses"][200]'.(2536)
```

I did some work starting from that solution, and obtained the functionality required without errors, and using slightly simpler type definitions, which require less type params.
In particular, my `PathMethod` type does not need any type param, and my `RequestParams` and `ResponseType` types need only 1 type param.

Here is a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC%20T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5%20FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsNhr4ADZyUGKXTnCJRWZo24JZJpDJQl4TXQfYDlEnmX7-eqnYGtDZdCF02FQmHwxoBFyUSgwYxgPAABUIRDgAF44ABrYDGCDofAikhOPkCuDC4gAWTkREW4qlMrlCuIJAA2uqiABdZX8vAAJWAhjCMGFqg4JAAPAAVOCgVBIYRkc1a4iLAB8er4pDNIotJs9Fp9ID9AYoU3UaFmmCQxhccAA-Eao%20bY-GTbQ0yjNLQE%20IDP7gOhkMBhNbVfaLldPTavYnk4GRcGdcJwxLI6bi3GE77gP6yOQMZcsQpiRQyRSKCaQIzuhbxFmcy5D-n9bL5WPo8QS7HaAuriRqyaXte15hq3Ba-XG0hm05KKBILAcDYIu8CYGACAAMKYIiiJ6u6gq9jOKbmgANHAGqIbOaoDtqYYABSSJG4iCihkjqEO4gaqRNAAHR0Wmsz2o6HQumoHoauG05YXWvhfs2x4mjWcAmkxRgsZgrrsaGFqUAAlMRUCcAgUTuu2mLAF2AruhxI7hmiwGRPABhQLBo4io0BnsMiNGIhA0h4eWElsbQaEMbJv40KEMDGUgcDoHIpR4cZiJoeQcDkbqLiyXAmBkPuTgBJQYGQdBiJ4QAREwrDsFwvAioIIjpWh6WyDARUrPsvhQP41FwI6UDLDi1TiMwkjclFDhwPQ9DYSQWJwNw4apDyyVQTBGVZWwnA8JGBXCOVJVyOVaKVYc5AuLV9WNc4vy0MAwC0G1lAdV1PUQZwYCIpgyDdANQ0pCN4FjWlmUsFNuWzUI83FaVy2SFtlS-K1QTHe5p1wOdHCXddSC3YN%20KPSl42vdl015fwX0Lb9YPdRDF1XTdEJ3QjSVPalE1vTlM35ZjxVIii6U4z1wp9WExPDaTSMvZNVPo0Qc0LfTqB-Z43hVTV-1GA1gM1HAwMjKDnW45D0OE9I7MpEAA) with the full solution.

As requested in the comments by [captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian), here is the full solution:

```
export interface paths {
  '/v1/some-path/:id': {
    get: {
      parameters: {
        query: {
          id: number;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
    post: {
      parameters: {
        body: {
          name: string;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
    delete: {
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}

type Path = keyof paths;
type PathMethod = keyof paths[Path];
type RequestParams<T extends PathMethod> = paths[Path][T] extends {parameters: any} ? paths[Path][T]['parameters'] : undefined;
type ResponseType<T extends PathMethod> = paths[Path][T] extends {responses: {200: {schema: {[x: string]: any}}}} ? keyof paths[Path][T]['responses'][200]['schema'] : undefined;

export const apiCall = <P extends Path, M extends PathMethod>(
  path: P,
  method: M,
  ...params: RequestParams<M> extends undefined ? [] : [RequestParams<M>]
): Promise<ResponseType<M>> => {
  const url = path;
  console.log('params', params);

  return fetch(url, { method }) as any;
};
```

**UPDATE:**

In the comments, [aurbano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262824/aurbano) noted that my solution only worked if `paths` has only 1 key. Here is an updated solution that works with 2 different paths.

```
export interface paths {
  '/v1/some-path/:id': {
    get: {
      parameters: {
        query: {
          id: number;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
    post: {
      parameters: {
        body: {
          name: string;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
    delete: {
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
  '/v2/some-path/:id': {
    patch: {
      parameters: {
        path: {
          id: number;
        };
        header: {};
      };
      responses: {
        /** OK */
        200: {
          schema: {
            id: number;
            name: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}

type Path = keyof paths;
type PathMethod<T extends Path> = keyof paths[T];
type RequestParams<P extends Path, M extends PathMethod<P>> = paths[P][M] extends {parameters: any} ? paths[P][M]['parameters'] : undefined;
type ResponseType<P extends Path, M extends PathMethod<P>> = paths[P][M] extends {responses: {200: {schema: {[x: string]: any}}}} ? keyof paths[P][M]['responses'][200]['schema'] : undefined;

export const apiCall = <P extends Path, M extends PathMethod<P>>(
  path: P,
  method: M,
  ...params: RequestParams<P, M> extends undefined ? [] : [RequestParams<P, M>]
): Promise<ResponseType<P, M>> => {
  const url = path;
  console.log('params', params);

  return fetch(url, { method: method as string }) as any;
};

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", "get", {
  header: {},
  query: {
    id: 1
  }
}); // Passes -> OK

apiCall("/v2/some-path/:id", "get", {
  header: {},
  query: {
    id: 1
  }
}); // Type error -> OK

apiCall("/v2/some-path/:id", "patch", {
  header: {},
  query: {
    id: 1
  }
}); // Type error -> OK

apiCall("/v2/some-path/:id", "patch", {
  header: {},
  path: {
    id: 1,
  }
}); // Passes -> OK

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", "get", {
  header: {},
  query: {
    id: 'ee'
  }
}); // Type error -> OK

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", "get", {
  query: {
    id: 1
  }
}); // Type error -> OK

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", "get"); // Type error -> OK

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", 'delete'); // Passes -> OK

apiCall("/v1/some-path/:id", "delete", {
  header: {},
  query: {
    id: 1
  }
}); // Type error -> OK
```

And here is an updated [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDmTGACwGc4BvAKDjgHIB6ANwEZ6SIBbYAWgOPoBcCACa0BFajTgBzYDHFUpUglExdUUEgslKaARwCuaAJ7bdukeKQGOAIzQBuHboC%20T8zSLBMwtArfONAHmUMAkkEgkYWYe9ABUcXAA8gDScHH0gVIATAAMuTEecCTYXhyYhUWIwlY29lDuVTRIasDiJDBQyNKNRcEe-UqDcMOQHZU0Kq0aWhJFthDCpnNVLVztnd29rttKXj5%20FMNBu3Ch4RCR0Svm8Ymp6ZlFeQU3HiVlFW9FlnDWdo4suY1m1ipskD0gVJjtDTsNhr4ADZyUGKXTnCJRWZo24JZJpDJQl4TXQfYDlEnmX7-eqnYGtDZdCF02FQmHwxr9BiMbJsTg8PhEQQiMRvPilElTdRobFQwWUqTUuqAvos-a%20KD%20OGnDGXLEKu74x5E-IKmhkinfDxKgENKFKEGMrb2kYs9nbfoBFyUSgwYxgPAABUIRDgAF44ABrYDGCDofAhkhOP0BuDB4gAWTkREWAB4ACpwUCoJDCMjpogAPnDUZjcYTxBIAG18wBdZP%20vAAJWAhjCMGDqg4JFzgaLIBLZbTIYANHAM%20PJ%20WQ1niHnA5XqxHBc3A62mxnW4vgKWyOQpSjNOJMEhjC44AB%20BukJt7g-72gXma0I-iAyl4B0GQYBhA7VMewuK5807Udj1PadiDnBdixPKcK1XHNhFHTcax3V990POCp3IXUrmxYkKAtL5yCbEAnQhVtr1vFwWPvJ9o1jeM8LfQ8m1oUisR-JsXg-KifzgP8AKApAQKcShQEgWA4GwPV4EwMAEAAYUwRFERrWCUPgiskKI5dM2zddNwACkkeU0xnSR1Ew8QMwcmgADpPKlWYez7DpBzUEdAyQ6tDKnf9fGkkDHzgJtf1i3yjH8zAhyCkLW0oABKcRAygTgECiXMIMxYBoIDUcQq3as0RUyJ4AMKA9O3ENGlq9hkXcxEIGkKzPxSwLaDnbzMrkmhQhgBqkDgdA5FKKyGsROdyDgJzFnEVbhDgTAyA6JlpBGTKtrIG9jCcAJKHUrSdMRKyACImFYdguF4ENhWEW651u2QYA%20lZ1UOcgXDcuA%20ygZYcWqcRmEkb0XBGuB6HoacSCxOBuGrVIfUu7TdLupheSegVXqEd7Pu%20360X%20zUjmB0HwecX5oaCSg4YcBGkc0zgwERTBkG6NGMZSLGNJxm77p5PlnsFN7ftu8UiApyQqf8WmjDBypGZhln4cRuBOY4bneaQfn0fxYWrtx8WCf5F7%20BJ2X5cVzxvA1FXbJDDWajgZhgdhnWkeDFGwgFs2LpF668ZYSWibtkRZfJpalZdgGgckOnPfEWhgGAWgtdZ9m9a5nm%20YhEPMbDi2xYe6PbaFe2ybkJ2QbV%20mlE15n891-XDZL-bTfL7GI-Fx6bel%20u4C%20xv-cLg3i%20N0v%206FivRcjkepeJuO51oJEUVoafA9RxfzZX4ea7HzeJ531Am%20Vmm05bjPvbz6fu7nk3BaAA).

Comment: Please share reproducable example in your answer. TS playground links is not reliable

Comment: This looks really promising!! However it only seems to work when there is one path in the `paths` interface - I left only one to simplify the example but have a look at the updated playground in the question :(

Comment: Just for precision's sake, I updated my solution to work with no errors and multiple paths 1 hour before @baboo updated his solution and wrote that mine was limited.