# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to a conditional type in Typescript in initializer

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to type a function in Typescript that takes an optional parameter. I would like the function to be valid for one argument only in case when the type of Events[Event] is void (or undefined).

This is what I have until now:

```js
type Events = {
    ping: void,
    debug: string;
};
const emit =
    <Event extends keyof Events, Data extends Events[Event]>
        (event: Event, data: Data extends void ? undefined : (Data | undefined) = undefined) =>
        console.log(`Event ${event} with data ${data}`);

emit("ping"); // should typecheck
emit("debug"); // should not typecheck
emit("debug", "output"); // should typecheck
```

The problem is that if I make the argument optional with a question mark, the typechecker does not catch the lack of argument in case the type is defined. So I have to use an initializer, but this initializer cannot be assigned. I get the error

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Data extends void ? undefined : Data | undefined'
```

But clearly the conditional type can only take values where undefined is assignable because either it is undefined or it is undefined or Data. Is this a bug in Typescript?

Comment: It's a limitation; described in [ms/TS#51488](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51488).  I'd rewrite your type to be a straightforward union with `undefined` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WK91KN).  (Note that I replaced `void` with `undefined` in your code, because `void` has really  side effects.)  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: In your example the second statement typechecks but it shouldn't. Is that intended? I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318011/optional-parameters-based-on-conditional-types

Comment: [That's true in your example also](https://tsplay.dev/NB42dW) and doesn't seem to be germane to the question as asked.  I interpret this question as "why is my initializer rejected" as the title implies.  Perhaps you should remove those lines from the code in the question and you could open a new question about it if resolving the initializer issue didn't resolve your underlying problem.