# No excess property check in discriminated union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Given is a discriminated union type `S1 | S2 | S3`:

```
type S1 = { d1: "foo"; }
type S2 = { d1: "bar"; isSuccess: true; }
type S3 = { d1: "baz"; isSuccess: false; errorMessage: string; }

type State = S1 | S2 | S3;

const testState: State = {
  d1: "foo",
  isSuccess: true, // no error, urgh.. 
  errorMessage: "Error!" // no error, urgh.. 
  // why no excess property check here?
}
```

I would expect TS to choose discriminant `d1`, as it is the only property that exists in all three states and is a valid singleton type candidate. `isSuccess` can't be chosen here, because it does not exist in `S1`.

Assuming this behavior, why aren't excess property checks respected and no error emitted, as soon as I type `isSuccess: true`, given `d1` has value `"foo"`?

Here is a [test sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=38&ssc=9&pln=38&pc=24#code/PTAEGMEMGcFNQIymgCwPYHdqgEZrQDayQB2oAJgJbTgBOlAtpSaQC6gAOtaHstrAT1DUAygFdw4WNGgBYAFAsG0jpCmgAwjFhIA3gtCHQg3qAAqtMbAAi1Oo2ZtQAXlC7h0cZOnQAXMctYAG5QAF8DIxN4ADFIAjhbGnomFhJ2V3dRCSkZfwAzOLgQvm5aAFkfSABzWH9oVnoSKpDw%20QjDKNARVkhWeFcLK0T7FKcAH1BY%20Js7ZMc0oIV2iDQSeuNpVm7e2q6evpc3ZaMPLxy-AKsAGmOjErRyypr-ACIAUVpSgEIX0BBQe60K6gMQkADWJEwZC4PD4glAAFpQAB5ADSX2WrVaCn%20UDgoAATMh0FhkA1mFUKLMHKl2DDePwhOQEAolCo1PAtHAifp5CdOtF8MM5rTDu5ma88vgXi1lp0AEKQWjCmlODIUBCvHBKmW4SDaurkpqyvmRASmRUALxVozSYo1Wsglt1gIqMmqu3qjWaYSWpo65vg2wOrkFaBt83YE0VyuptqjoCtEdpiza-pWa3YfXqwd2ubFt0MEtALylaBeN3TJ1dT1270%20Dx%20fzAgOBoIhUM43AZ8KRaIx6axftx2lAAGYQXBsKwUPAqElVXa8twGBBR0hSORCazIMpoKp1FzYBPefzA10kOri6XpSaz6YRESr5qS9raLqst5cpdgr7050RAnZ9HWdEJP3OfJCl-Gt3WeMlvRNOVz3zVwRCQCZH1ADCx1TZZwFWdZsy2fY8xIgsqyMa8ywrQtTmyHx-Aaa5DH%20SEAQbIEQVoKoUAAOl40AMBQIQ2NgAAPc4u1hRkIFncAwVAWdaFgAB%20WiYOgD1Xg%20b5flYtB2NKNtuL4gShJEgzxMk%20k4SEcA5IUpTVMxBRQiAA) I made to understand the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript a | b allows combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both) (It also came up recently as https://stackoverflow.com/q/59462318/1426891.)

Comment: What's weird is that `State` has to specify all three types before no error is displayed.  If it's `S1 | S2` or `S1 | S3` or `S2 | S3`, you get the errors as expected.  Also, changing `S3`'s `isSuccess` to `true` preserves the errors.  It's when `isSuccess` is a `boolean` rather than `true` that errors stop occurring.

Comment: This actually looks like a compiler bug to me.  Adding `as S1`, `as S2`, and `as S3` to the end of your `testState` declaration shows that you only don't get the error when it's interpreting your object as an `S1`.  If it knows it's an `S1`, then it should know what properties are and aren't allowed.

Comment: @JeffBowmansupportsMonica No, this is not a duplicate. In your mentioned posts, no valid discriminated union types were used. For example, in `{ value: number, data: string } | { value2: number, note: string };` `number` and `string` are no valid singleton types. But I used string literal types `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"` for prop `d1` here, which can act as a discriminant. You can find more infos [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695). Please reopen the question.

Comment: @dx_over_dt indeed! For me it seems buggish, too.

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35890

Comment: Voted to reopen, but it may be helpful here (and in the future) to edit in links to similar questions in your question and identify ways in which your question is distinct.