# Add an extra type property base on another property

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

**#1** I have a type for the column that is an object. Column can be filterable or not, if `isFilterable` is `true` then the type `Column` should require: `filterType`, `isTopBarFilter?` and `options` (BUT only if `filterType` is `'SELECT'` - **#2**).

```
type Column = {
  name: string;
  isFilterable: boolean; // passing here false should be equal with not passing the property at all (if possible)

  // below properties should exist in type only if isFilterable = true
  filterType: 'SELECT' | 'TEXT' | 'DATE';
  options: string[]; // this property should exist in type only if filterType = 'SELECT'
  isTopBarFilter?: boolean;
};
```

I do such type with use of types union and it work almost properly

```
type FilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable: true;
  filterType: 'SELECT' | 'TEXT' | 'DATE';
  options: string[];
  isTopBarFilter?: boolean;
};

type NonFilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable: false;
};

type Column = (NonFilterableColumn | FilterableColumn) & {
  name: string;
};
```

but:

1. As I mentioned before (**#2**) `Column` should require `options` only if `filterType` is `'SELECT'`. I have tried to do this with types union but it became works strange:

```
type FilterableSelectColumn = {
  filterType: 'SELECT';
  options: string[];
};

type FilterableNonSelectColumn = {
  filterType: 'TEXT' | 'DATE' | 'NUMBER';
};

type FilterableColumn = (FilterableSelectColumn | FilterableNonSelectColumn) & {
  isFilterable: true;
  isTopBarFilter?: boolean;
};

type NonFilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable: false;
};

type Column = (FilterableColumn | NonFilterableColumn) & {
  name: string;
};

// e.g
const col: Column = {
  name: 'col2',
  isFilterable: false,
  filterType: 'SELECT', // unwanted
  isTopBarFilter: false, // unwanted
  options: ['option1'], // unwanted
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgQwEYIgZQtgY2AGEB7BAVwFsA7KAXigG8AoKKAM0WRQBVwIALigByHAFEAMuOK8RAbjZRSYYHFI0AzsM3AUcGgHMA2gF1FAX0UtQkWN1SZsAOQ15CJctTqNW7Lkio-JDCIrziABpyUAA%20ogAiAILhIrGizgCqALIAQuIASgosViw2AvaB6FgQZJS0DFAAFPCVTrj4EES13mktPG2uNO6dnnU0AJRQAGTMSnCafY7VwnoUEIrs87wqOWgoiygA-MIYpOQQaDSW1rbQgwdt3fW%20cwsOVdjCHGgImuvFN3KTx8TQe1WBaXu70eXlokxmfigNDQVCEUF0%20iM11KAHocVAIAA6QwsAgaXRQMkIYQQl7sZGo0JUgBMIgANK8wZ9OD8-hz-O9gmixFIZHI2VA8VAKDQAO6XZAAE1e2zAu327y%20vIgEqlMvlNCVShUanJwmMIhN6hoAEYRKZdfj9QqIMqrEA)

If I set `isFilterable` to false, TS doesn't suggesting unwanted properties (it is good) but also doesn't show error if I pass these unwanted props (it is bad)

2. My solution also force to pass `isFilterable` even if it is `false`, as I mentioned above I want to pass it only if it is `true`

Is there way to improve my solution(or another solution) to achieve what I described at the beginning (**#1**)?

Comment: Oh, that's a good one. You chanced on how discriminated unions behave with intersections. I will draft up an answer tomorrow if no one beats me to it. Here is a proof of your idea working just fine with only nested discriminated unions: https://tsplay.dev/WzyJRm

Comment: @OlegValter Thank you for your response. I have been tried to improve my code basing on the snippet you sent above but it not quit fit and I can't handle it. I will be grateful I you would help me exactly with my case.

Comment: huh, guess I got distracted by the other stuff, sorry - thank you for pinging me back on it :( I will give it a shot shortly. I need to search for a good reference first - I think I saw a discussion on the TS source repo about a similar issue

Comment: sorry, I removed a comment above because in the time passed I forgot that your question was not about nested discriminated unions, but about union of object types with intersections. That is a separate issue (probably related to the issue #9919, but I need to investigate first)

Comment: phew - finally got to it :) The issue turned out to be different, but solvable. Apologies for the edit and subsequent rollback, I have a small experiment I needed to run, please don't mind it - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few nights I managed to do it, I have two solutions:

**1.**

```
type FilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable: true;
  isTopBarFilter?: boolean;
} & (
  | {
      filterType: 'SELECT';
      options: string[];
    }
  | {
      filterType: 'TEXT' | 'DATE';
    });

type NonFilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable?: undefined; // same result with never
  filterType?: undefined; // same result with never
};

type ColumnBaseFields = {
  name: string;
};

type Column = (FilterableColumn | NonFilterableColumn) & ColumnBaseFields;

const column: Column = {
  name: 'someName',
  isFilterable: true,
  filterType: 'SELECT',
  options: ['option'],
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgQwEYIgYQPYICuAtgHZQC8UA3gFBRRwDO8Sqm2AXFMCoRAG56jJgBU8YAEJoUrZCgD83DHgIQ0pIQF8oAMigAKYQB8awhgwBmieaPARuAcgDKAUQAyrnKMdCLFiWA4PFImbiZeOFIAcwBtAF0-Cy0TM38rG1Q7SCdRVwANHyhTRwARAEE833MoLQBKIVpQSCgAORC5dixcAhJyKjoGZk70bqUoQlIAEwhrUggpgSgAemWoJjRiaBQIJkIkKAB3OGAACyh5gDdUYWs2FGyIccmZuYWl1fXN7d394COTucrjctI1mtB8EQyNImBB4BAEFMmJQ0hdvuFIjFtEkGE17FBIX0UQYRhwelDyKZ2qRSd1CWQ6noCb1oWhYfDEUxGgBjEIRKC8incen9VGkdFQRxMPBbVrfRwAGmEw0yoy4PD4ECVGXujycbk83kVwkCwVC3FijlNIUc8SVoKAA)

It works as I wanted, Typescript errors appears for the cases, but error descriptions are inaccurate. I noticed that TypeScript works strange with many unions on the same nesting level

and because of it I made up the second solution with nested filters options

**2.**

```
type FilterSettings = (
  | {
      filterType: 'SELECT';
      options: string[];
    }
  | {
      filterType: 'TEXT';
    }) & {
  isTopBarFilter?: boolean;
};

type FilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable: true;
  filterSettings: FilterSettings;
};

type NonFilterableColumn = {
  isFilterable?: undefined; // same result with never
};

type ColumnBaseFields = {
  name: string;
};

type Column = (FilterableColumn | NonFilterableColumn) & ColumnBaseFields;

const column: Column = {
  name: 'someName',
  isFilterable: true,
  filterSettings: {
    filterType: 'SELECT',
    options: ['option']
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgZQsYcB2BzAZygF4oAKAKCigB8oBvK65gM0WRQBVwIAuKAORoAogBlhAYU4CA3E2ZQA9mGyKcBfgWApceANoBdOQoC+TOowXU2SVN0j8BnYQA1px5iYCUUAGQMmOAJOZQAhAEMUeFsUAH5+ACNFRQQIcJw5EzkKUEhYdlRwhNSJFIBXAFscEgDqIOiOItT+bTKIDxsODCxdDXyY7ux8Akzs3OgAOTUGwuKIUoRK6tJLKHqClCaIeKgynAATCDYcCH2ZKAB6C6gCcIroFAgCMqQoAHc4YAALKBOAN1QFCyFByPCgCyWEQIEHgEAQ+yIKyYODufBu2l0oxB43B5SqNTIM02cwh+LoUxwRK2pJwPn8NKhMLgcIR2QAxmotFAOYsqvwaTVVij7o4CIp7hNUQIADSBAhUuYtFBtWXWDaDXr8VZqmL2NFCMSSaSq5jKVTqfh6ARmuBqAQGJhmLJAA)

Works fine, typescript tell us exactly when some key is missed and when some key is unwanted.

I hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how the distribution law affects how the intersections and unions resolve in your case. First, the following:

```ts
type OuterUnionMemberA = (UnionMemberA | UnionMemberB) & IntersectedA;
```

is equivalent to this:

```ts
type OuterUnionMemberA = (UnionMemberA & IntersectedA) | (UnionMemberB & IntersectedA);
```

which in turns leads us to the following:

```ts
type ComplexType = (OuterUnionMemberA | IntersectedB) & OuterIntersected;
```

being equivalent to this complex union:

```ts
type ComplexType = (UnionMemberA & IntersectedA & OuterIntersected) | (UnionMemberB & IntersectedA & OuterIntersected) | (IntersectedB & OuterIntersected);
```

Let's resolve the aliases manually and see what it leaves us with:

```ts
type ComplexType = { 
  filterType: 'SELECT'; 
  options: string[];
  isFilterable: true; 
  extraProp?: boolean;
  name: string;
} | {
  filterType: 'TEXT' | 'DATE' | 'NUMBER';
  isFilterable: true; 
  extraProp?: boolean;
  name: string;
} | {
  isFilterable: false;
  name: string
}
```

To verify our expectation of this being the same type, let's do an equality test:

```ts
type isSupertype = ComplexType extends ComplexTypeUnwrapped ? true : false; //true
type isSubtype = ComplexTypeUnwrapped extends ComplexType ? true : false; //true
```

All the above was done to make the following clear:

1. There are 2 discriminant properties (`filterType` and `isFilterable`);
2. In this case, the [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) is not performed;

The combination of the above turns out to be a confirmed design limitation of TypeScript (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35890) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34751) issues on the source repository and [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59505653/11407695) that lead to the former issue being raised).

But what can you do about it? `never` to the rescue: being forbidden as a property is pretty much the same as having a type `never`, so a simple change to the `isFilterable` property accordingly to avoid making `isFilterable` a second discriminant property (extra optional property omitted for simplicity) should do the trick:

```ts
type Column = 
(
  { name: string, isFilterable:true,filterType:"SELECT",options:string[] } | 
  { name: string, isFilterable:true,filterType:"TEXT"|"DATE" } | 
  { name: string, isFilterable:never } |
  { name: string, isFilterable:false } //allows "name-only" case
)

const notFilterableAll: Column = { name: 'col2', isFilterable:false };
const notFilterableText: Column = { name: 'col2', filterType: "TEXT" }; //Property 'isFilterable' is missing;
const notFilterableSelect: Column = { name: "col2", filterType: "SELECT", options: [] }; //Property 'isFilterable' is missing;
const notFilterableSelectMissingOpts: Column = { name: "col2", filterType: "SELECT" }; //Type '"SELECT"' is not assignable to type '"TEXT" | "DATE"';
const selectFilterOk: Column = { name: 'col2', isFilterable:true, filterType: "SELECT", options: [] }; //OK
const textFilter: Column = { name: "col2", isFilterable:true, filterType: "TEXT" }; //OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwLIQLYCMICcCCUAvFAN5QBmCANsHgCrgQBcUA5AMoCiAMlwML02AbihIwwZHADOracFwI4AcwDaAXVEBfYQChQkWIhTpseAELEylGnVyNIrNvS4ANIVAA+7ACL4XbF7sAHIwqOZcAEoiUDq6+kxQAJJwdtIQAMZ0ACaEJOQI0gBitngAhljULFAKAK4QohAAHgplAAq44gD8rFhISFVlcLF6BtApaZk5lvlQhSW05ZXVFGXU6dp6CYYA8rV2E3jpWRDZVuRwZRjV8ooqI-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-Ii3VIsjUWoWoMGGEhdG+GULgff8n1dRsD2WZhW0lfMGB1AAiPUSw0yVg39GsVA0WIgik+9hWrADlHk-cPyUlS1O1RwNMXegNM8DS1y4DSTO8My-0suTZXfJYlTgCAADc8F8-yZMC2sbJChUlJVdJYl0cF4mZGRgEFJBgCS5t8GoahOQGESxOsAK2FFCVEqbFLvwebLWTgfLCuWeg7TK4TRPOczqhqgY6psLV5xctw3JGN1uzwUB2AUuyqkCQooAwQppAnXQWtytqCoaqoOAgKosh6ir+oCjTat00aCx1KAtOLQQbv0mQA3UaaTVmyCQAW2zQogFbkPW6RNpUPQdry-bFMO46plQDbax2CQqyE87Zku67XUc8btOez6jV5NhHv1NygahqAylBhBlEuZYaiQGpEmJ1yfO8Tz-G83dIfSE7obsHYAGszr6jG4qG8VDUWgHlLwtVbvUxwHrxtzXVeqtjJ0N0dgAaW2llcroFokpFyrpIsq7hpu6XkqVFSFac6oJvcHytZNXWgA)

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. Idea with `never` covers most cases, but still in the case `{ name: 'col2' }` TS needs isFilterable, but should't :/

Comment: @bastej - just noticed that I made a typo and left the readers wonder what law I meant :) Re: `{ 
name: string }` case - yeah, that's, unfortunately, the price to pay for the solution - I don't think you can completely solve it right now. At least it's on the team's tracks...

Comment: @bastej - you can add the 4th union member in `Column` type like this: `{ name: string, isFilterable:false }` to at least give you the ability to pass the property as `false` as in your initial solution (we only use the `never` trick to break the second discriminant), but that's it

Comment: I hope this is at least better than no error on unwanted properties, though :)