# React - Typescript interfaces - errors when get props from union types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I use react with typescript.

I want to require only one parameter be accepted from `prop3` | `prop4`. I use a union type like this:

```
interface General {
  prop1?: boolean
  prop2?: boolean
}

interface Option1 extends General {
  prop3: boolean
}

interface Option2 extends General {
  prop4: boolean
}

type Option1orOtion2 = Option1 | Option2
```

If I get `prop3` I don't want that `prop4` will be accepted.

When I do that I get errors about those values. What I do worng?

```
export default function({
  prop1 = true,
  prop2 = true,
  prop3 = true, // error: Property 'prop3' does not exist on type 'Option1orOtion2'
  prop4 = true  // error: Property 'prop4' does not exist on type 'Option1orOtion2'
}: Option1orOtion2) {
  return <></>
}
```

**EDIT**: When I do that with variable there aren't errors, but let me to pass `prop3` and also `prop4`, and I want to get a error about it (`Option1` **or** `Option2` ).

```
var data: Option1orOtion2 = {prop3: false, prop4: false}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try ->  type Option1orOtion2 = Option1 & Option2

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried it already and the error was gone, but it doesn't stop me from sending both `prop3` and `prop4` as I expect. Any idea?

Comment: I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688375/13029900).

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Here's a playground example:
https://typescript-play.js.org/?jsx=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPYAOGyA3gFDLIx54BcyGYUoA5gNxkC+ZZoksiFLkIYAgsggAPSCAAmxdFmFFSFZACM4Ueo2Yh2XHn2jwkyZRlQTpEOQsw58K8pU0AvHU1YduZMAE8CISdiAF5zEPEAHwiRVA4yBDwQRmQAWX8AYTwAWwJk2zBkcIAKEioaABoNODdqzShkTnoLAEpigD5VSigIMABXKBBkACIAC2ARnwSklKLeuWhi5BL20K6XZF6BoeQAHgzsvILwCrxQkeo8EZq3C-cbgHoOrg4gA

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem can be solved using function prototypes, which is used to make overload in ts.

For your case, I have 2 solutions

```
interface General {
    prop1?: boolean
    prop2?: boolean
}
  
interface Option1 extends General {
    prop3: boolean
}
  
interface Option2 extends General {
    prop4: boolean
}
```

Using function prototypes to limit the type of parameter that can be given. (I assume the return type to be string, just change it to what you want)

```
export default function test(param: Option1): string;
export default function test(param: Option2): string;
```

First solution: using union

```
export default function test({
    prop1 = true,
    prop2 = true
}: Option1 | Option2): string {
    return ''
}
```

For this solution, I haven't found any solution to create default for prop3 and prop4.

Second Solution

```
interface Param extends General {
    prop3?: boolean;
    prop4?: boolean;
}
export default function test({
    prop1 = true,
    prop2 = true,
    prop3 = true,
    prop4 = true
}: Param): string {
    return ''
}
```

I make another interface which has the prop3 and prop4 set to optional attributes.

Because of the function prototypes, if I call it like below, it will cause error

```
test({prop4: true, prop3: true}) // error
```