# One or the other prop type for React component with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to create a Table that renders either by a `data` prop or you can directly put custom rendered stuff via `children`. For that I need a type that accepts either `data` or `children`.

I found these solutions already, but it somehow doesn't work with React Component. Only with plain objects.

- [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)
- [Typescript Interface - Possible to make "one or the other" properties required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required)

So basically I created three interfaces, one with base types, one with `data` and one with `children`. But when I create the React component, it yells at me that those props don't exist on `TableProps`

Does anyone know what could I be doing wrong?
Here is sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-shadow-vw148?file=/src/table.tsx

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function compName = ({data,children}:{data?: [type];children?: [type]}){
// logic
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck