# One of two property name

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type B = {
 c: string
}
    
type T = {
  a: string
  b: B
}
```

I want to make T2 that will look like

```
type T2 = {
  a: string
  ['b' or 'prefixB']: B
}
```

Basically I want to have T with a and b or prefixB property - do you know how to do it in the eases way? Something like one of two

Comment: You can check the second answer of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript a | b allows combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Aa = {a: string}
type T2 =  Aa & ({prefixB: string} | {b: string})

const foo: T2 = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
}
foo.a // a
foo.b // b
foo.prefixB // Property 'prefixB' does not exist

const foo2: T2 = {
  a: "a",
  prefixB: "prefixB"
}
foo2.a // string
foo2.prefixB // prefixB
foo2.b // Property 'b' does not exist
```

i think this is work

---

update

```
type Aa = {a: string}
type B = {
  c: string
}

type T2 =  Aa & ({prefixB: B} | {b: B})

const foo: T2 = {
  a: "a",
  b: {
    c: "obj"
  },
}
foo.a // a
foo.b // { c: "obj" }
foo.prefixB // Property 'prefixB' does not exist

const foo2: T2 = {
  a: "a",
  prefixB: {
    c: "obj"
  }
}
foo2.a // a
foo2.prefixB // { c: "obj" }
foo2.b // Property 'b' does not exist

const foo3: T2 = {
  a: "a",
  prefixB: {
    c: "obj"
  },
  b: {
    c: "obj"
  }
}
foo3.a // a
foo3.prefixB //  Property 'prefixB' does not exist
foo3.b // Property 'b' does not exist
```

Comment: hi, unfortunately your solution is wrong, it still possible do agree both values. Please try on B when it's object

Comment: @user16195583 yes possible do agree, but You can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest non-generic way is to define `T2` as:

```ts
type T2 = 
  | { a: string, b: B, prefixB?: never } 
  | { a: string, b?: never, prefixB: B }
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvpPRN)

Comment: good idea - it works perfect, thanks! I'm curious if we can simplify somehow :D. I'm filling that I miss some cool part of TS

Comment: You may implement some sort of generic helper to generate such types. But that will not be 'easier` definitely.