# Typescript Interface to contain a non-mandatory property or another

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I know that there are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required) here but mine is a little different.

There is an Interface that can have one or another property, let's call them `black` and `white` they aren't mandatory, so the Interface is valid without them and it is valid with one of them.

Good:

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
}
```

Good:

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
  black?: boolean;
}
```

Good:

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
  white?: boolean;
}
```

Bad: (or it could be Good if we can check that maximum one of either `black` or `white` is there)

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
  black?: boolean;
  white?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I was being a bit slow on the question you just deleted. You' probably already figured it out, but you wanted `[disabledClassNames]: disabled` in the object literal; [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508490/157247).

Answer (score 4):

Because TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing), it is not an error for an object to have excess properties, unless you explicitly disallow this by setting the property's optional type to `never`, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=33&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgQwMYGsDyZgEsD2A7BOKAXigG8AoKKAI0VQH4AuWnHOCBPAbiqgHcAFlmARmUPBABuEAE68AvrwqhIUAOrDRGbPkIlyfOshTjJM+XyEixLGmw5dFy1dAByCALbRSlagW8WAGdgWSw8AHNFChVwaABRAA8vMA4DAAoPbygAMlh6dExcAjgASigAHyhMr2g8zRsdYsJS5SR8EKgIZM9UiABGFiSUtN8oAHoAKj5qagA9BcWFigAVOKCoHAAzKDBZHEhZUCgAcmNUE6gEWWhw9t6EbDoIADooNbUzh048S6wNvA4YBXIJBLARAjPKDAHDQuKncxyE4vdIAJgAzKjUeVJuM+AEICwTgSTgAaIwFFihACuEHJ1Gsoipslp5KUMXaeE63RGEFRQx6fQMfgktSJJPptEp0JZdIo7IonO5go46IFvOF+LFCNqZKsWkJMtZ8u4QA)

```ts
type BlackOptional = {
  black?: boolean;
  white?: never;
};

type WhiteOptional = {
  black?: never;
  white?: boolean;
};

type Name = {
  name: string;
}

type Example = (Name & BlackOptional) | (Name & WhiteOptional);

const example1: Example = { /*
      ^^^^^^^^
Types of property 'black' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322) */
  name: 'name',
  black: true,
  white: true,
};

const example2: Example = {
  name: 'name',
  black: true,
};

const example3: Example = {
  name: 'name',
  white: true,
};
```