# typescript is not able to Inference my type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

As I filtered vehicles based on isCar so Ts should infer it as an array of Cars but TS infer it as Foo[]. How can I have a conditional type based on isCar??

```js
interface Vehicle {
  driveName: string
}

interface Bicycle extends Vehicle {
  isCar: false,
  saddleColor: string
}

interface Car extends Vehicle {
  isCar: true
  plate: string
}


type Foo = Bicycle | Car


const vehicles: Foo[] = [
  {
    driveName: "foo",
    isCar: true,
    plate: "1111"
  },
  {
    driveName: "bar",
    isCar: false,
    saddleColor: "red"
  }
]


const c = vehicles.filter(({ isCar }) => isCar) // typeof c is not Car
```

[my code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGxQbwChlkATKYANwgDk4BbCALmQGcwKQBzQgX0MKhIsRCgBC2AJ64UEAB6QQpVmkzY8yIiWCsAwnCgt4OVhAA0xNnFKk8ugPY57hth1A9+g8NHhJk+qGR5RWVVLBlNSx0Alg4AVwhLAAccOEgWdk4PAUIwSSSUADF7e2QAXmQJBGkNAB9-AxyEexB2ZGpwvFYWYvsAbQBdcuQ+yy0SMgpqOkYWACIYErmLCeRog1ioBJWJlLTmZDmARhOjucteHfGScipaBgO5gCMDZcttPQ3kY1MdklZrLYIA4nC45lAIKRziR+AMmi02ghhh11BBWAA6GDAHDCAAUuPwa0+gV4AEpygA+IkBckAelpyDyBXsMGQSJ0yBA9jADSgQA)

I found these questions but was not able to find an answer to my problem

[Typescript Interface - Possible to make "one or the other" properties required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required)

[Typescript asserting types if they have one property true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227664/typescript-asserting-types-if-they-have-one-property-true-or-false)

Comment: Please include your code in the question. So people can see your problem without leaving SO.

Comment: @Eldar I'm new to stackoverflow and not able to post image. follow the link I put in post

Comment: Does one these posts: [Why can't TypeScript infer type from filtered arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032214/why-cant-typescript-infer-type-from-filtered-arrays) or [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro) , answer your question?

Comment: @mohammadizanloo55 please always include minimum reproducible example in your question, otherwise your question will probably be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom typeguard:

```js
interface Vehicle {
  driveName: string
}

interface Bicycle extends Vehicle {
  isCar: false,
  saddleColor: string
}

interface Car extends Vehicle {
  isCar: true
  plate: string
}


type Foo = Bicycle | Car


const vehicles: Foo[] = [
  {
    driveName: "foo",
    isCar: true,
    plate: "1111"
  },
  {
    driveName: "bar",
    isCar: false,
    saddleColor: "red"
  }
]

const isCar = (vehicle: Foo): vehicle is Car => vehicle.isCar

const c = vehicles.filter(isCar) // typeof c is not Car
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w17qYm)