# In react (TS), how can I make sure if one prop is passed to a component, another prop is also required to be passed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

For example I have a component that takes in these props through an interface:

```
interface InputProps {
   error?: boolean;
   errorText?: string;
}
```

```
const Input = ({error, errorText}: InputProps) => { etc etc }
```

How do I make it so that if this component is called in another part of the code i.e.

```
<Input />
```

"error" has to be passed as a prop if "errorText" has been passed.

Not sure where to start

Comment: Does it have to be a typescript solution? Because proptypes can do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do this? You can simply set this error to true/false inside your `<Input />` component by doing this:

```
interface InputProps {
   errorText?: string;
}

const Input = ({error, errorText}: InputProps) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(errorText){
            setError(true)
        }
    },[errorText])

    return <></>
}
```

Additionally you can also write a helper function inside this component to listen to the changes being made to your `<Input />` component and keep modifying error in realtime. I am not sure what this component does but I am assuming this is a form component so you can do this by adding an `onChange` listener.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688375/12138592) suggested solution, that fits your description.